# Plot two graphs in a same plot

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, r-faq

I would like to plot y1 and y2 in the same plot.

```
x  <- seq(-2, 2, 0.05)
y1 <- pnorm(x)
y2 <- pnorm(x, 1, 1)
plot(x, y1, type = "l", col = "red")
plot(x, y2, type = "l", col = "green")
```

But when I do it like this, they are not plotted in the same plot together.

In Matlab one can do `hold on`, but does anyone know how to do this in R?

Comment: Check out `?curve`. Use `add=TRUE`.

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3777174/plotting-two-variables-as-lines-using-ggplot2-on-the-same-graph) for more specific ggplot2 answers.

Answer (score 726, accepted):

`lines()` or `points()` will add to the existing graph, but will not create a new window. So you'd need to do

```
plot(x,y1,type="l",col="red")
lines(x,y2,col="green")
```

Comment: Why doesn't it work in the following simple example?

> plot(sin)
> lines(cos)
Error in as.double(y) : 
  cannot coerce type 'builtin' to vector of type 'double'

Comment: This is easy to see. With plot(sin), you are passing a function instead of actual data. plot() will detect this and in turn use plot.function() to plot your function (read up on multiple dispatch to learn more about this). However, lines.function() is not defined, so lines() doesn't know what to do with a parameter of class function. lines can only deal with your data and time series objects of class ts.

Comment: @Frank Do it like this: `plot(sin); curve(cos, add=TRUE)`.

Comment: How to use the same if x is different? Say, I have x1 and y1 for one graph and add another graph of x2 and y2 in the same graph. Both x1 and x2 have same range but different values.

Comment: It's exactly the same: `lines(x2,y2,...)` instead of `lines(x,y2,...)`

Comment: What's the most straightforward way to add a legend to this?

Comment: Can you use 2 different scales on y-axis for the lines?

Comment: Is it possible to make R scale the plot dimensions with respect to both `y1` and `y2` without manually writing min/max/limit stuff?

Comment: Is there a way to assign plot and lines to a variable, without using ggplot?

Answer (score 257):

You can also use `par` and plot on the same graph but different axis. Something as follows:

```
plot( x, y1, type="l", col="red" )
par(new=TRUE)
plot( x, y2, type="l", col="green" )
```

If you read in detail about `par` in `R`, you will be able to generate really interesting graphs.  Another book to look at is Paul Murrel's R Graphics.

Comment: My R gives me an error:
Error in par(fig(new = TRUE)) : could not find function "fig"

Comment: Does  your method preserve the right scale (y axis) for the two plots?

Comment: @uvts_cvs Yes, it preserves the original graph in toto.

Comment: The problem with this is it will rewrite several plot elements. I would include `xlab="", ylab="", ...` and a few others in the second `plot`.

Comment: can you please look at my question if you have time? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65650991/r-overlaying-points-on-a-graph thanks

Answer (score 145):

When constructing multilayer plots one should consider `ggplot` package. The idea is to   create a graphical object with basic aesthetics and enhance it incrementally.

`ggplot` style requires data to be packed in `data.frame`.

```
# Data generation
x  <- seq(-2, 2, 0.05)
y1 <- pnorm(x)
y2 <- pnorm(x,1,1)
df <- data.frame(x,y1,y2)
```

Basic solution:

```
require(ggplot2)

ggplot(df, aes(x)) +                    # basic graphical object
  geom_line(aes(y=y1), colour="red") +  # first layer
  geom_line(aes(y=y2), colour="green")  # second layer
```

Here `+ operator` is used to add extra layers to basic object.

With `ggplot` you have access to graphical object on every stage of plotting. Say, usual step-by-step setup can look like this:

```
g <- ggplot(df, aes(x))
g <- g + geom_line(aes(y=y1), colour="red")
g <- g + geom_line(aes(y=y2), colour="green")
g
```

`g` produces the plot, and you can see it at every stage (well, after creation of at least one layer). Further enchantments of the plot are also made with created object. For example, we can add labels for axises:

```
g <- g + ylab("Y") + xlab("X")
g
```

Final `g` looks like:

[image]

**UPDATE (2013-11-08):**

As pointed out in comments, `ggplot`'s philosophy suggests using data in long format.
You can refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19039094/1796914) in order to see the corresponding code.

Comment: As [suggested by Henrik](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19038732/946850), the data really should be in "long" format, `ggplot` handles this more naturally than the "wide" format you use.

Comment: @Henrik: No, thank you for your answer in the first place. Perhaps the author of this answer can edit it so that it fits well with `ggplot`'s philosophy...

Comment: taught me defining x on ggplot(aes()) and then y by itself on geom_*(). Nice!

Answer (score 60):

I think that the answer you are looking for is:

```
plot(first thing to plot)
plot(second thing to plot,add=TRUE)
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work, it gives an `"add" is not a graphical parameter` warning then just prints the second plot over the first one.

Comment: @WaldirLeoncio see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6789055/r-inconsistency-why-add-t-sometimes-works-and-sometimes-not-in-the-plot-funct

Comment: One nice benefit of this is that it seems to keep the axes limits and titles consistent.  Some of the previous methods cause R to draw two sets of tick marks on the y axis, unless you go through the trouble of specifying more options.  Needless to say, having two sets of tick marks on the axes could be very misleading.

Comment: the add parameter works for some plot methods, but not the base/default one in R

Comment: I got the same error `"add" is not a graphical parameter`. My R is `R version 3.2.3 (2015-12-10)`. You could use `par(new=TRUE)` command between these plots.

Answer (score 40):

Use the `matplot` function:

```
matplot(x, cbind(y1,y2),type="l",col=c("red","green"),lty=c(1,1))
```

use this if `y1` and `y2` are evaluated at the same `x` points. It scales the Y-axis to fit whichever is bigger (`y1` or `y2`), unlike some of the other answers here that will clip `y2` if it gets bigger than `y1` (ggplot solutions mostly are okay with this).

Alternatively, and if the two lines don't have the same x-coordinates, set the axis limits on the first plot and add:

```
x1  <- seq(-2, 2, 0.05)
x2  <- seq(-3, 3, 0.05)
y1 <- pnorm(x1)
y2 <- pnorm(x2,1,1)

plot(x1,y1,ylim=range(c(y1,y2)),xlim=range(c(x1,x2)), type="l",col="red")
lines(x2,y2,col="green")
```

Am astonished this Q is 4 years old and nobody has mentioned `matplot` or `x/ylim`...

Comment: The range() function here is especially useful.

Answer (score 34):

**tl;dr:** You want to use `curve` (with `add=TRUE`) or `lines`.

---

I disagree with `par(new=TRUE)` because that will double-print tick-marks and axis labels. Eg

[image: sine and parabola]

*The output of `plot(sin); par(new=T); plot( function(x) x**2 )`.*

Look how messed up the vertical axis labels are! Since the ranges are different you would need to set `ylim=c(lowest point between the two functions, highest point between the two functions)`, which is less easy than what I'm about to show you---and *way* less easy if you want to add not just two curves, but many.

---

What always confused me about plotting is the difference between `curve` and `lines`. *(If you can't remember that these are the names of the two important plotting commands, just [sing](http://www.tubechop.com/watch/5461987) it.)*

#### Here's the big difference between `curve` and `lines`.

`curve` will plot a function, like `curve(sin)`. `lines` plots points with x and y values, like: `lines( x=0:10, y=sin(0:10) )`.

And here's a minor difference: `curve` needs to be called with `add=TRUE` for what you're trying to do, while `lines` already assumes you're adding to an existing plot.

[image: id & sine]

*Here's the result of calling `plot(0:2); curve(sin)`.*

---

Behind the scenes, check out `methods(plot)`. And check `body( plot.function )[[5]]`. When you call `plot(sin)` R figures out that `sin` is a function (not y values) and uses the `plot.function` method, which ends up calling `curve`. So `curve` is the tool meant to handle functions.

Answer (score 27):

if you want to split the plot into two columns (2 plots next to each other), you can do it like this:

```
par(mfrow=c(1,2))

plot(x)

plot(y)
```

[Reference Link](http://www.statmethods.net/advgraphs/layout.html)

Answer (score 23):

As described by @redmode, you may plot the two lines in the same graphical device using `ggplot`. In that answer the data were in a 'wide' format. However, when using `ggplot` it is generally most convenient to keep the data in a data frame in a 'long' format. Then, by using different 'grouping variables' in the `aes`thetics arguments, properties of the line, such as linetype or colour, will vary according to the grouping variable, and corresponding legends will appear.

In this case, we can use the `colour` aessthetics, which matches colour of the lines to different levels of a variable in the data set (here: y1 vs y2). But first we need to melt the data from wide to long format, using e.g. the function 'melt' from `reshape2` package. Other methods to reshape the data are described here: [Reshaping data.frame from wide to long format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2185252/reshaping-data-frame-from-wide-to-long-format).

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)

# original data in a 'wide' format
x  <- seq(-2, 2, 0.05)
y1 <- pnorm(x)
y2 <- pnorm(x, 1, 1)
df <- data.frame(x, y1, y2)

# melt the data to a long format
df2 <- melt(data = df, id.vars = "x")

# plot, using the aesthetics argument 'colour'
ggplot(data = df2, aes(x = x, y = value, colour = variable)) + geom_line()
```

[image]

Answer (score 18):

If you are using base graphics (i.e. not lattice/ grid graphics), then you can mimic MATLAB's hold on feature by using the points/lines/polygons functions to add additional details to your plots without starting a new plot. In the case of a multiplot layout, you can use `par(mfg=...)` to pick which plot you add things to.

Answer (score 18):

You can use points for the overplot, that is.

```
plot(x1, y1,col='red')

points(x2,y2,col='blue')
```

Answer (score 13):

Idiomatic Matlab `plot(x1,y1,x2,y2)` can be translated in R with `ggplot2` for example in this way:

```
x1 <- seq(1,10,.2)
df1 <- data.frame(x=x1,y=log(x1),type="Log")
x2 <- seq(1,10)
df2 <- data.frame(x=x2,y=cumsum(1/x2),type="Harmonic")

df <- rbind(df1,df2)

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df)+geom_line(aes(x,y,colour=type))
```

[image]

<sup>Inspired by Tingting Zhao's [Dual line plots with different range of x-axis Using ggplot2](https://rpubs.com/zhaott/53275).</sup>

Answer (score 11):

Rather than keeping the values to be plotted in an array, store them in a matrix.  By default the entire matrix will be treated as one data set.  However if you add the same number of modifiers to the plot, e.g. the col(), as you have rows in the matrix, R will figure out that each row should be treated independently.  For example:

```
x = matrix( c(21,50,80,41), nrow=2 )
y = matrix( c(1,2,1,2), nrow=2 )
plot(x, y, col("red","blue")
```

This should work unless your data sets are of differing sizes.

Comment: This gives: Error in if (as.factor) { : argument is not interpretable as logical

Answer (score 11):

You could use the `ggplotly()` function from the **plotly** package to turn any of the **gggplot2** examples here into an interactive plot, but I think this sort of plot is better without **ggplot2**:

```
# call Plotly and enter username and key
library(plotly)
x  <- seq(-2, 2, 0.05)
y1 <- pnorm(x)
y2 <- pnorm(x, 1, 1)

plot_ly(x = x) %>%
  add_lines(y = y1, color = I("red"), name = "Red") %>%
  add_lines(y = y2, color = I("green"), name = "Green")
```

[image]

Comment: plotly looks brilliant; is it free ?

Comment: @denis, there is unlimited free public plotting and paid private plotting or on-premise options. See the [plans page](https://plot.ly/product/plans/).

Comment: The plotly R package is now 100% free and open source (MIT licensed). You can use it with or without a plotly account.

Comment: can you please take a look at my question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65650991/r-overlaying-points-on-a-graph thanks!

Answer (score 7):

You can also create your plot using [ggvis](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggvis/index.html):

```
library(ggvis)

x  <- seq(-2, 2, 0.05)
y1 <- pnorm(x)
y2 <- pnorm(x,1,1)
df <- data.frame(x, y1, y2)

df %>%
  ggvis(~x, ~y1, stroke := 'red') %>%
  layer_paths() %>%
  layer_paths(data = df, x = ~x, y = ~y2, stroke := 'blue')
```

This will create the following plot:

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Using `plotly` (adding solution from `plotly` with primary and secondary y axis- It seems to be missing):

```
library(plotly)     
x  <- seq(-2, 2, 0.05)
y1 <- pnorm(x)
y2 <- pnorm(x, 1, 1)

df=cbind.data.frame(x,y1,y2)

  plot_ly(df) %>%
    add_trace(x=~x,y=~y1,name = 'Line 1',type = 'scatter',mode = 'lines+markers',connectgaps = TRUE) %>%
    add_trace(x=~x,y=~y2,name = 'Line 2',type = 'scatter',mode = 'lines+markers',connectgaps = TRUE,yaxis = "y2") %>%
    layout(title = 'Title',
       xaxis = list(title = "X-axis title"),
       yaxis2 = list(side = 'right', overlaying = "y", title = 'secondary y axis', showgrid = FALSE, zeroline = FALSE))
```

Screenshot from working demo:

[image]

Comment: I compiled the code and does not work, first marked an error in %>% and I deleted it, then marked an error `Error in library(plotly) : there is no package called ‘plotly’` why?

Comment: Have you installed the package `plotly`? You need to install the package using `install.packages("plotly")` command.

Answer (score 5):

we can also use lattice library

```
library(lattice)
x <- seq(-2,2,0.05)
y1 <- pnorm(x)
y2 <- pnorm(x,1,1)
xyplot(y1 + y2 ~ x, ylab = "y1 and y2", type = "l", auto.key = list(points = FALSE,lines = TRUE))
```

For specific colors

```
xyplot(y1 + y2 ~ x,ylab = "y1 and y2", type = "l", auto.key = list(points = F,lines = T), par.settings = list(superpose.line = list(col = c("red","green"))))
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Use `curve` for mathematical functions.
And use add=TRUE to use the same plot and axis.

```
curve( log2 , to=5     , col="black", ylab="log's(.)")
curve( log  , add=TRUE , col="red" )
curve( log10, add=TRUE , col="blue" )
abline( h=0 )
```

[image]