# Plotting two variables as lines using ggplot2 on the same graph

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph, time-series, r-faq

A very newbish question, but say I have data like this:

```
test_data <-
  data.frame(
    var0 = 100 + c(0, cumsum(runif(49, -20, 20))),
    var1 = 150 + c(0, cumsum(runif(49, -10, 10))),
    date = seq(as.Date("2002-01-01"), by="1 month", length.out=100)
  )
```

How can I plot both time series `var0` and `var1` on the same graph, with `date` on the x-axis, using `ggplot2`?  Bonus points if you make `var0` and `var1` different colours, and can include a legend!

I'm sure this is very simple, but I can't find any examples out there.

Answer (score 444, accepted):

For a small number of variables, you can build the plot manually yourself:

```
ggplot(test_data, aes(date)) + 
  geom_line(aes(y = var0, colour = "var0")) + 
  geom_line(aes(y = var1, colour = "var1"))
```

Comment: nice example, but how to customize my own colours (E.g. black and orange)?, because it seems that you are using `colour=` as the variable name.

Comment: even `colour='var_names'` as specified by hadley works fine. but @DaveX - would be more specific if one wants to choose specific colors rather than automatically selected colours by the function.

Comment: How can I add a legend to it?

Comment: @user1700890, the legend seems to be added automatically

Comment: If the colour variable is numeric, it may be necessary to `as.character()` on it first.

Answer (score 409):

The general approach is to convert the data to long format (using `melt()` from package `reshape` or `reshape2`) or `gather()`/`pivot_longer()` from the `tidyr` package:

```r
library("ggplot2")
library("tidyr")
library("reshape2")

## convert to long format with tidyr::pivot_longer
test_data_long_tidyr <- pivot_longer(test_data, cols = starts_with("var"))

ggplot(data=test_data_long_tidyr,
       aes(x=date, y=value, colour=name)) +
  geom_line() ## output not shown, it's equivalent to the below graph (with a tiny difference in the legend title)

## convert to long format with reshape2::melt
test_data_long <- melt(test_data, id="date")  

ggplot(data=test_data_long,
       aes(x=date, y=value, colour=variable)) +
  geom_line()
```

[image]

Also see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2185252/reshaping-data-frame-from-wide-to-long-format) on reshaping data from wide to long.

Comment: You can also use the `gather()` function of `tidyr` package to melt the data: `gather(test_data, variable, value, -date)`

Comment: reshape2, and tidyr::gather are superseded (see https://github.com/hadley/reshape and `?tidyr::gather`). Hadley recommends to use  "pivot_longer" - I have added an example with the latter

Answer (score 44):

You need the data to be in "tall" format instead of "wide" for ggplot2. "wide" means having an observation per row with each variable as a different column (like you have now). You need to convert it to a "tall" format where you have a column that tells you the name of the variable and another column that tells you the value of the variable. The process of passing from wide to tall is usually called "melting". You can use `tidyr::gather` to melt your data frame:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)

test_data <-
  data.frame(
    var0 = 100 + c(0, cumsum(runif(49, -20, 20))),
    var1 = 150 + c(0, cumsum(runif(49, -10, 10))),
    date = seq(as.Date("2002-01-01"), by="1 month", length.out=100)
  )
test_data %>%
    gather(key,value, var0, var1) %>%
    ggplot(aes(x=date, y=value, colour=key)) +
    geom_line()
```

[image: multiple series ggplot2]

Just to be clear the `data` that `ggplot` is consuming after piping it via `gather` looks like this:

```
date        key     value
2002-01-01  var0    100.00000
2002-02-01  var0    115.16388 
...
2007-11-01  var1    114.86302
2007-12-01  var1    119.30996
```

Answer (score 18):

I am also new to R but trying to understand how ggplot works I think I get another way to do it. I just share probably not as a complete perfect solution but to add some different points of view.

I know ggplot is made to work with dataframes better but maybe it can be also sometimes useful to know that you can directly plot two vectors without using a dataframe.

Loading data. Original date vector length is 100 while var0 and var1 have length 50 so I only plot the available data (first 50 dates).

```
var0 <- 100 + c(0, cumsum(runif(49, -20, 20)))
var1 <- 150 + c(0, cumsum(runif(49, -10, 10)))
date <- seq(as.Date("2002-01-01"), by="1 month", length.out=50)
```

Plotting

```
ggplot() + geom_line(aes(x=date,y=var0),color='red') + 
           geom_line(aes(x=date,y=var1),color='blue') + 
           ylab('Values')+xlab('date')
```

[image]

However I was not able to add a correct legend using this format. Does anyone know how?

Comment: This adds a legend

`ggplot() + 
 geom_line(aes(x=date,y=var0, group=1, colour = 'red')) + 
  geom_line(aes(x=date,y=var1, group = 2, colour = 'blue')) + 
 ylab('Values')+xlab('date')`

Comment: What's the difference between this and the accepted answer, besides that yours doesn't have a legend?

Comment: @camille as indicated, the only difference is this way does not use dataframe as input, just the vectors directly

Answer (score 13):

Using your data:

```
test_data <- data.frame(
var0 = 100 + c(0, cumsum(runif(49, -20, 20))),
var1 = 150 + c(0, cumsum(runif(49, -10, 10))),
Dates = seq.Date(as.Date("2002-01-01"), by="1 month", length.out=100))
```

I create a stacked version which is what `ggplot()` would like to work with:

```
stacked <- with(test_data,
                data.frame(value = c(var0, var1),
                           variable = factor(rep(c("Var0","Var1"),
                                                 each = NROW(test_data))),
                           Dates = rep(Dates, 2)))
```

In this case producing `stacked` was quite easy as we only had to do a couple of manipulations, but `reshape()` and the `reshape` and `reshape2` might be useful if you have a more complex real data set to manipulate.

Once the data are in this stacked form, it only requires a simple `ggplot()` call to produce the plot you wanted with all the extras (one reason why higher-level plotting packages like `lattice` and `ggplot2` are so useful):

```
require(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(stacked, aes(Dates, value, colour = variable))
p + geom_line()
```

I'll leave it to you to tidy up the axis labels, legend title etc.

HTH

Comment: I think you have a misplaced parens in your code up there. I think this is what you are after: stacked <- with(test_data, data.frame(value = c(var0, var1), variable = factor(rep(c("Var0", "Var1"))), each = NROW(test_data), Dates = rep(date, 2))). Also, what is the purpose of the column "each"? And is this not just a more convoluted and less efficient way to melt the data as shown by rcs? I guess I could imagine an instance where melt wouldn't get the job done, but it is almost certainly the right tool for this job unless I'm missing something?

Comment: @chase, sorry, that is Emacs ESS getting the indenting wrong. each is an argument to `rep()`, so we really are only getting 3 cols in `stacked`. I'll edit the code to make the indent clearer.

Comment: @chase; your comment about `melt()` is well taken, and I note that the reshape[2] package would be useful here. I'm not that familiar with reshape2 and for such a simple manipulation doing it by hand is more complex than a call to `melt()`, it was less effort as I didn't need to read how to use `melt()`. And rcs sneaked in with his answer whilst I was producing mine; when I started the reply there had been no answers. more than one way to skin a cat - as they say! ;-)