# Changing line colors with ggplot()

Tags: r, ggplot2

I don't use ggplot2 that much, but today I thought I'd give it a go on some graphs. But I can't figure out how to manually control colors in `geom_line()`

I'm sure I'm overlooking something simple, but here's my test code:

```
x <- c(1:20, 1:20)
variable <- c(rep("y1", 20), rep("y2", 20) )
value <- c(rnorm(20), rnorm(20,.5) )

df <- data.frame(x, variable, value )

d <- ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=value, group=variable, colour=variable ) ) + 
            geom_line(size=2)
d
```

which gives me the expected output:

[image]

I thought all I had to do was something simple like:

```
d +  scale_fill_manual(values=c("#CC6666", "#9999CC"))
```

But that changes nothing. What am I missing?

Answer (score 144, accepted):

`color` and `fill` are separate aesthetics. Since you want to modify the **color** you need to use the corresponding scale:

```
d + scale_color_manual(values=c("#CC6666", "#9999CC"))
```

is what you want.

Comment: Can you please explain what is the difference between color and fill?

Comment: @losaliens for two-dimensional geoms color is the outside (border) color, fill is the inside (fill) color.

Answer (score 8):

Here's a minimal reproducible example of another way to change line colours (try running it):

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)

iris %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = Petal.Length)) +
  geom_line(aes(y = Sepal.Length), color = "green") +
  geom_line(aes(y = Sepal.Width), color = "blue")
```

[image]

This way can be particularly useful when you added the lines [manually](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3780353/5783745).