# How to change one line color in geom_line

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have 24 groups that I have plotted using geom_line in ggplot2.  I was wondering whether there is a quick way to change the colour of one of those particular groups to black without specifying the colours of the other 23?

My code:

```
ggplot(max, aes(x = dap,y = cf, group=variables, colour = variables)) +
                  geom_line(size=0.5)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [R: changing line colors with ggplot()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5171263/r-changing-line-colors-with-ggplot)

Comment: Yep - that is what I'm using... but I want to try and not specify the colours of every other group and just override the colour of just one.

Comment: If you know the order of the groups (they're factors, so it shld be easy to do that) then you can use `rep` to generate the vector of colors and just substitute one color in the position of the one you want to highlight. i.e. `line.cols <- rep("#7f7f7f",24) ; line.cols[4] <- "DIFFERENT"`

Comment: I could but I still want the other groups to be different colours.

Comment: `line.cols <- terrain.colors(24) ; line.cols[4] <- "DIFFERENT"` :-) or `rainbow` or `heat.colors` or `topo.colors` or `cm.colors` (and many outside `base` & `grDevices` packages.