# changing plot color in R

Tags: r

I am new to R. I have the following code for a plot, but I do not know how to change color of the bars. In the legend section, I also want to replace color with headache. I also need to change label in y axis to "frequency". How can I do it ?

```
library(tidyverse)

dat= data_frame(rating=1:5, headache=c(167,82, 132, 182, 200), No_headache=c(28, 22, 20, 27, 29))
dat = dat %>%
  gather(key=color, value=value, -rating)
ggplot(data=dat, aes(x=rating, y=value, fill=color)) + 
  geom_bar(stat='identity', position='dodge')
```

Comment: `+ labs(fill = "headache", y = "frequency")`

Comment: @Gregor, but I tried this before, it totally removes the no_headache data, and reshape the plot.

Comment: Works fine when I do it. The `labs` function only modifies legend and axis labels.

Comment: @Gregor, thank you. Sorry my mistake. Do you know how to change the colors?

Comment: That, I would say, is a duplicate of this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5171263/903061 , just use `fill` instead of `color` since it is the color filling in the bars.

Comment: @Gregor, Thank you. It changed the color.