# change line colour ggplot (geom_line)

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom

I still very new using GGPLOT, but ive created the following graphic in which i would like to switch the colors blue and red. Should be simple enough but i cannot figure it out.

```
df <- structure(list(Sex = c("M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "W", 
"W", "W", "W", "W", "W", "W"), age_cat = structure(c(1L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L), .Label = c("<40", 
"41-50", "51-60", "61-70", "71-80", "81-90", "90+"), class = "factor"), 
    DD = c(42L, 88L, 289L, 558L, 527L, 174L, 22L, 27L, 36L, 206L, 
    347L, 321L, 160L, 29L), pop = c(36642L, 16327L, 20232L, 18068L, 
    14025L, 5555L, 1293L, 35887L, 16444L, 20178L, 17965L, 14437L, 
    7150L, 2300L), proportion = c(0.114622564270509, 0.538984504195504, 
    1.428430209569, 3.08833296435687, 3.75757575757576, 3.13231323132313, 
    1.7014694508894, 0.0752361579402012, 0.218924835806373, 1.02091386658737, 
    1.9315335374339, 2.22345362609961, 2.23776223776224, 1.26086956521739
    ), lower = c(0.082621962613957, 0.432499099174075, 1.26946115577044, 
    2.8408823120445, 3.44891013496043, 2.69000601596679, 1.06929480146528, 
    0.0495867729368698, 0.153377923598767, 0.886828947142727, 
    1.73530361873497, 1.98914206124244, 1.90751612365318, 0.846006018532107
    ), upper = c(0.154905173671422, 0.663628389658291, 1.6015714811397, 
    3.35102939015014, 4.08561035940466, 3.6247050150149, 2.56476800800746, 
    0.10944592449968, 0.302956684874059, 1.16937842460687, 2.14353263545661, 
    2.47728262910991, 2.60770261266057, 1.80583393021473)), row.names = c(NA, 
-14L), class = "data.frame")
```

Below is the script i've used, in which i get (sex = M) in red and (sex = W)in bliue. [image]

```
ggplot(data = prevalence2021GGPLOT,
       aes(x = age_cat, y = proportion, color = Sex))+
  geom_point()+
  labs(title="Prevalence 2021", y="Prevalence (%)", x="Age category") +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=(lower),
                    ymax=(upper)), width=.2) +
  theme_bw()+
  geom_line(aes(group = unlist(Sex)))
```

How do i make sex = M blue and sex = W red??

Comment: This can be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/a/5171329/1315767

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `scale_color_manual` to manually change the colours in ggplot2. The first colour corresponds to the first modality of your fill variable.

```
ggplot(data = df,
   aes(x = age_cat, y = proportion, color = Sex))+ geom_point()+
   labs(title="Prevalence 2021", y="Prevalence (%)", x="Age category") +
   geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=(lower),
                ymax=(upper)), width=.2) +
   theme_bw()+
   geom_line(aes(group = unlist(Sex)))+
   scale_color_manual(values=c("blue", "red"))
```

As the result :

[image: graphic]

you can find the documentation of the ggplot2 graphics on R here :

- [data_to_viz](https://www.data-to-viz.com/)
- [scale_color_manual](http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/ggplot2-colors-how-to-change-colors-automatically-and-manually)

Answer (score 2):

This works.  I need to point to df  to use your sample df.  Edited it per suggestion.

```
ggplot(data = df,
       aes(x = age_cat, y = proportion, color = Sex))+
  geom_point()+
  labs(title="Prevalence 2021", y="Prevalence (%)", x="Age category") +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=(lower),
                    ymax=(upper)), width=.2) +
  theme_bw()+
  geom_line(aes(group = unlist(Sex))) +
ggplot(data = df,
       aes(x = age_cat, y = proportion, color = Sex))+
  geom_point()+
  labs(title="Prevalence 2021", y="Prevalence (%)", x="Age category") +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=(lower),
                    ymax=(upper)), width=.2) +
  theme_bw()+
  geom_line(aes(group = unlist(Sex))) +
  scale_color_manual(values=c(M="darkblue", W="darkred"))
```

Comment: To make sure the colors are assigend to the right values, use a named vector `c(M = "darkblue", W = "darkred")`