# Control over legends of multiple layer plot in ggplot2

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

My question is closely related to [R: Custom Legend for Multiple Layer ggplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18394391/r-custom-legend-for-multiple-layer-ggplot) , and to [Format legend for multiple layers ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13256694/format-legend-for-multiple-layers-ggplot2)  namely: I want to create custom legends for multiple-layer plot. However, there is a subtle difference:
In the original questions, the desired effect was to separate from two different groupping methods: `fill` and `color` and that's why it was possible to use two different `scale_XXX` functions. In my case I create a plot
that contains points (one layer) and lines (second layer). Both layers are differentiated by color:

```
x <- seq(0, 10, .1)
y <- sin(x)
lbl <- ifelse(y > 0, 'positive', 'non-positive')
data.one <- data.frame(x=x, y=y, lbl=lbl)

data.two <- data.frame(x=c(0, 10, 0, 10), y=c(-0.5, -0.5, 0.5, 0.5), classification=c('low', 'low', 'high', 'high'))
plt <- ggplot(data.one) + geom_point(aes(x, y, color=lbl)) + scale_color_discrete(name='one', guide='legend')
plt <- plt + geom_line(data=data.two, aes(x, y, color=classification)) + scale_color_discrete(name='two', guide='legend')
print(plt)
```

Here is the result:

[image: before]

What I want is to separate the legends for points and lines, so that the legend looks like this:

[image: after]

I could not find a way to adopt the approach of the cited questions to my situation. Any ideas?

Comment: You may have a look at [this post and comments therein](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17642190/how-to-set-multiple-legends-for-the-same-aesthetic-in-ggplot2), e.g. "ggplot2 by design will not allow multiple legends for the same aesthetic". Thus, solutions are likely to be hack-ish.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following is a hack. It extracts the legends from temporary plots and then combines everything using `grid.arrange`.

```
g_legend<-function(a.gplot){
  tmp <- ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(a.gplot))
  leg <- which(sapply(tmp$grobs, function(x) x$name) == "guide-box")
  legend <- tmp$grobs[[leg]]
  return(legend)}

n <- 4; cols <- hcl(h=seq(15, 375-360/n, length=n)%%360, c=100, l=65)

cols1 <- cols[4:3]
names(cols1) <-  c("positive", "non-positive")
plt_1 <- ggplot(data.one) + 
  geom_point(data=data.one,aes(x, y, color=lbl)) +
  scale_color_manual(values=cols1)


cols2 <- cols[1:2]
names(cols2) <-  c("high", "low")
plt_2 <- ggplot(data.one) + 
  geom_line(data=data.two, aes(x, y, color=classification)) +
  scale_color_manual(values=cols2)
  

mylegend_1<-g_legend(plt_1)
mylegend_2<-g_legend(plt_2)

plt <- ggplot(data.one) + 
  geom_point(data=data.one,aes(x, y, color=lbl)) +
  geom_line(data=data.two, aes(x, y, color=classification)) +
  scale_color_discrete(guide="none")

library(gridExtra)
grid.arrange(plt,
             arrangeGrob(mylegend_1, mylegend_2, nrow=6),
             ncol=2,widths=c(7,1))
```

[image]

You'd need to fiddle a bit more to get the justification as in your expected output.