# How do I correctly set legend colors in ggplot2 with procedural graph generation?

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, legend-properties

I'm trying to create a framework for easy plotting of our data sets. The current idea is to initiate a `ggplot` graph, add layers to it, then display or save it. My code looks like this:

```
initPlot <- function(title = "", data = NULL){
    if(is.null(data)) data <- GLOBDATA
    plot <- ggplot(data, aes(jahr))
    plot <- plot + scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(2001, 2012, 1))
    textTheme <- element_text(size=6, face="plain", color="black", family="AvantGarde")
    lineTheme <- element_line(color="black", size=0)
    plot <- plot + theme(
        text = textTheme, 
        axis.text  = textTheme, 
        axis.ticks = lineTheme,
        axis.line  = lineTheme,
        axis.title = element_blank(),
        plot.background = element_rect(fill="#f0f0f0"),
        strip.background = element_rect(fill="#f0f0f0"),
        panel.background = element_rect(fill="#f0f0f0"),
        panel.grid = element_blank(),
        legend.position = "bottom"
    )
    plot <- plot + guides(color = guide_legend(title = title))
    PLOTGLOB <<- plot
    plot
}

plotConfidence <- function(columns, color = "red", title = "", label = "", plot = NULL){
    plot <- plotLine(columns, "black", label, plot, 1)
    plot <- plot + geom_ribbon(columns, alpha = 0.3, fill = color, linetype=0)
    PLOTGLOB <<- plot
    plot
}

plotLine <- function(column, color = "black", label = "", plot = NULL, size = 1){
    if(is.null(plot)) plot <- PLOTGLOB
    plot <- plot + geom_line(column, color = color, size = size)
    PLOTGLOB <<- plot
    plot
}
```

I then call my code like this:

```
initPlot("title")
plotConfidence( 
    aes(
        y = jSOEP_aqne_ip_fgt060_f_alle, 
        ymin = jSOEP_aqne_ip_lfgt060_f_alle, 
        ymax = jSOEP_aqne_ip_ufgt060_f_alle, color="Alle", fill="Alle"
    ),
    "red")
plotConfidence( 
    aes(
        y = jSOEP_aqne_ip_fgt060_f_mann, 
        ymin = jSOEP_aqne_ip_lfgt060_f_mann, 
        ymax = jSOEP_aqne_ip_ufgt060_f_mann, color="Männer", fill="Männer"
    ),
    "blue", , label="Männer")
```

Which produces the following graphic:

[image]

As you can see, the legend colors don't match up with the corresponding geom_ribbons, in fact, both are of the color "blue" (found that out by setting the alpha to 1 temporarily). How do I fix this?

Here's the data I want to plot:

```
GLOBDATA <- structure(list(jSOEP_aqne_ip_fgt060_f_alle = c(0.117169998586178, 
0.122670002281666, 0.131659999489784, 0.132029995322227, 0.140119999647141, 
0.142869994044304, 0.136739999055862, 0.140990003943443, 0.146730005741119, 
0.149069994688034, 0.141920000314713, 0.142879992723465), jSOEP_aqne_ip_lfgt060_f_alle = c(0.114249996840954, 
0.119199998676777, 0.128110006451607, 0.12814000248909, 0.136230006814003, 
0.139119997620583, 0.132400006055832, 0.137409999966621, 0.142560005187988, 
0.14478999376297, 0.137840002775192, 0.138579994440079), jSOEP_aqne_ip_ufgt060_f_alle = c(0.120090000331402, 
0.126139998435974, 0.135220006108284, 0.135920003056526, 0.143999993801117, 
0.146630004048347, 0.141090005636215, 0.144580006599426, 0.15090000629425, 
0.153359994292259, 0.146009996533394, 0.147180005908012), jSOEP_aqne_ip_fgt060_f_mann = c(0.100199997425079, 
0.106820002198219, 0.117770001292229, 0.117349997162819, 0.126489996910095, 
0.130469992756844, 0.12601999938488, 0.127340003848076, 0.132960006594658, 
0.135379999876022, 0.132510006427765, 0.13782000541687), jSOEP_aqne_ip_lfgt060_f_mann = c(0.0951400026679039, 
0.101929999887943, 0.112829998135567, 0.112510003149509, 0.121720001101494, 
0.12372999638319, 0.120829999446869, 0.121650002896786, 0.127389997243881, 
0.128470003604889, 0.12533999979496, 0.131980001926422), jSOEP_aqne_ip_ufgt060_f_mann = c(0.105259999632835, 
0.111709997057915, 0.122720003128052, 0.122189998626709, 0.131270006299019, 
0.137209996581078, 0.131219998002052, 0.133019998669624, 0.138539999723434, 
0.142289996147156, 0.139679998159409, 0.143659994006157)), .Names = c("jSOEP_aqne_ip_fgt060_f_alle", 
"jSOEP_aqne_ip_lfgt060_f_alle", "jSOEP_aqne_ip_ufgt060_f_alle", 
"jSOEP_aqne_ip_fgt060_f_mann", "jSOEP_aqne_ip_lfgt060_f_mann", 
"jSOEP_aqne_ip_ufgt060_f_mann"))
```

Comment: Can you provide some data? Would be good to know what the structure looks like.

Comment: added data at the bottom of my post

Comment: That's not helpful. Please provide some data with which we can run your code (e.g. using `dput()`) or at least `head()`

Comment: Sorry, fixed that hopefully.

Comment: see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19911134/control-over-legends-of-multiple-layer-plot-in-ggplot2/19912121#19912121)

Comment: I don't understand how that applies to my problem, could you be more specific please?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for sharing your data. Unfortunately as it stands it does not run. `GlOBDATA` is a `list` structure and there is no `jahr` amongst some other omissions.

This answer does not attempt to create a general function or amend yours but hopefully does suggest another way to structure your data.

By restructuring your data, you can map variables to colours and this will automatically produce the `legend`.

```
library(ggplot2)    

# create dataframe from your list
temp <- do.call(cbind.data.frame, GLOBDATA)

# Change data format
# your data is organised in wide format as mean, upper CI, lower CI (i think) 
# for both 'alle' and 'mann'. By stacking these after renaming for consistent
# column names, we can then easily map aesthetics in ggplot.
# create a grouping variable (grp) to map aesthetics to.

df1 <- setNames(temp[grepl('alle', names(temp))], c('mn', 'lower', 'upper'))
df1$grp <- 'alle'
df2 <- setNames(temp[grepl('mann', names(temp))], c('mn', 'lower', 'upper'))
df2$grp <- 'mann'
df <- rbind(df1, df2)

# add year
df$year <- 2000 + seq(nrow(temp))

# plot
p <- ggplot(df, aes(x=year, y=mn , ymin=lower, ymax=upper, colour=grp, fill=grp)) + 
            geom_line(size = 1, colour="black") + 
            geom_ribbon(alpha = 0.3, linetype=0) + 
            scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(2001, 2012, 1)) +
            scale_fill_manual(values=c('alle' = 'red', 'mann'='blue'))

p <- p + 
  theme(
  text = element_text(size=6, face="plain", color="black", family="AvantGarde"), 
  axis.text  = element_text(size=6, face="plain", color="black", family="AvantGarde"), 
  axis.ticks = element_line(color="black", size=0.5),
  axis.line  = element_line(color="black", size=0.5),
  axis.title = element_blank(),
  plot.background = element_rect(fill="#f0f0f0"),
  strip.background = element_rect(fill="#f0f0f0"),
  panel.background = element_rect(fill="#f0f0f0"),
  panel.grid = element_blank(),
  legend.position = "bottom",
  legend.title=element_blank()
  )
```

[image]

So by tweaking how your data is organised and your functions a little you should be able to map variables to aesthetics and automatically generate a legend.