# ggplot2: Legend for NA in scale_fill_brewer

Tags: r, ggplot2

I wonder how I can get legend category for `NA` values in `scale_fill_brewer`. Here is my MWE.

```
set.seed(12345)
dat <- 
  data.frame(
    Row = rep(x = LETTERS[1:5], times = 10)
    , Col = rep(x = LETTERS[1:10], each = 5)
    , Y = c(rnorm(n = 48, mean = 500, sd = 1), NA, NA)
  )

dat$Y1 <-  addNA(cut(log(dat$Y), 5))

levels(dat$Y1)
[1] "(6.21,6.212]"  "(6.212,6.214]" "(6.214,6.216]" "(6.216,6.218]" "(6.218,6.22]"  NA   


library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data =  dat, aes(x = Row, y = Col)) + 
  geom_tile(aes(fill = Y1), colour = "white") +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "PRGn")
```

[image]

Comment: I think this is related to your question: https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/issues/410

Comment: Thanks a lot @aosmith for your helpful comment. Would you mind to change your comment to answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could explicitly treat the missing values as another level of your `Y1` factor to get it on your legend.

After cutting the variable as before, you will want to add `NA` to the levels of the factor.  Here I add it as the last level.

```
dat$Y1 <-  cut(log(dat$Y), 5)
levels(dat$Y1) <- c(levels(dat$Y1), "NA")
```

Then change all the missing values to the character string `NA`.

```
dat$Y1[is.na(dat$Y1)] <- "NA"
```

This makes `NA` part of the legend in your plot:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

I've found a workaround without changing the original data frame, adding an extra legend based on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16389636/in-ggplot2-how-can-i-add-additional-legend):

```
ggplot(data =  dat, aes(x = Row, y = Col)) + 
   geom_tile(aes(fill = Y1), colour = "white") +
   scale_fill_brewer(palette = "PRGn")+
   geom_point(data = dat, aes(size="NA"), shape =NA, colour = "grey95")+
   guides(size=guide_legend("NA", override.aes=list(shape=15, size = 10)))
```

[image]

Colouring the NAs:

```
ggplot(data =  dat, aes(x = Row, y = Col)) + 
   geom_tile(aes(fill = Y1), colour = "white") +
   scale_fill_brewer(palette = "PRGn", na.value="red")+
   geom_point(data = dat, aes(size="NA"), shape =NA, colour = "red")+
   guides(size=guide_legend("NA", override.aes=list(shape=15, size = 10)))
```

[image]