# Areas with missing data are dropped from geom_sf /ggplot2 map. Why?

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, maps, r-sf

I have troubles to print maps with missing data.

I am able to produce an "empty" shapefile:

```
empty.shape.sf <- 
  ggplot(BiH.shape.sf)+
  geom_sf(fill="grey",colour="black")+
  theme(legend.position="none",
        axis.title=element_blank(),
        axis.text=element_blank(),
        axis.ticks = element_blank(),
        strip.text.y = element_text(size = 10),
        panel.background=element_rect(fill="white"))

print(empty.shape.sf)
```

[image]
I then add data to the shapefile

```
df.shape <- dplyr::left_join(BiH.shape.sf, data, by="ID_3")
```

and produce the new maps.

```
data.map <- df.shape%>%
  filter(year==2000|year==2004)%>%
  ggplot()+
  geom_sf(aes(fill=res), colour="black")+
  theme(legend.position="none",
        axis.title=element_blank(),
        axis.text=element_blank(),
        axis.ticks = element_blank(),
        strip.text.y = element_text(size = 10),
        panel.background=element_rect(fill="white"))+
  scale_fill_gradient(low="blue", high="red", limits=c(0,100))+
  facet_wrap(~year)

print(data.map)
```

[image]

Why are the areas for which the projected data is missing without borders/dropped? I would have assumed that by using left_join all borders/areas remain preserved. How can I keep these borders/areas? Is there no other way than to create a 'complete' dataset which includes rows with NAs for each missing area?

Comment: See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42365483/add-a-box-for-the-na-values-to-the-ggplot-legend-for-a-continous-map) for how to add NA values to maps with gradient fill.  It's difficult to make any suggestions specific to your map and data, since you have not shown the data you are using in your question

Comment: ggplot2 does not drop `NA`'s silently. Were you given a warning message about this?

Answer (score 3):

I think you can simply add the argument `na.value` to your call to scale_fill_gradient. Here is a reproducible example using the North Carolina shapefile included in the `sf` package:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(sf)
nc <- sf::st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package = "sf"), quiet = TRUE)
nc$BIR74[1] <- NA
nc %>% ggplot()+
  geom_sf(aes(fill=BIR74), colour="white")+
  theme(legend.position="none",
        axis.title=element_blank(),
        axis.text=element_blank(),
        axis.ticks = element_blank(),
        strip.text.y = element_text(size = 10),
        panel.background=element_rect(fill="white"))+
  scale_fill_gradient(low="blue", high="red",na.value = "black")
```

[image: scale_fill_discrete sf with NA value]

Since I can't reproduce your particular example, I'd guess that you want to use a different type of `join`, otherwise the shapefile will retain those missing rows (and missing shapes) as mentioned.

Comment: I don't think this is the solution. If I run your example and remove the na.value argument, we simply get a grey area representing NA rather than black. I bet this problem has been caused by the filter()