# Shape's border color is darker than the fill after setting alpha in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to plot a scatter plot that has the points slightly transparent to show if there is a cluster of points that are overlapped. However, I found that the shape's border is slightly darker than the fill. I wonder if there is a way to either match the color of the fill and shape border color or remove the shape border. I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52272818/15706665) that was answered years ago. However, when I try to use the schemes mentioned in the answer, it seems not to work. More specifically, setting the color to transparent only creates a "white" border of the circle. If possible, I would like to stick with the "circle" shape. I tried multiple circles, `shape = c(16, 19, 20, 21)`, but with no luck.

Here is a toy dataset:

```
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(1)
data <- data.frame(x = rnorm(1000), y = rnorm(1000))
## this option has a border with the same color but it is "darker"
ggplot(data) +
  geom_point(aes(x = x, y = y), fill = "grey", size = 2, alpha = 0.7) +
  theme_classic()


## this option has a "white" border"
ggplot(data) +
  geom_point(aes(x = x, y = y), fill = "grey", colour = "transparent", size = 2, alpha = 0.7, shape = 21) +
  theme_classic()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For both options you could remove the outline by setting `stroke=0` in `geom_point`:

```r
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(1)
data <- data.frame(x = rnorm(100), y = rnorm(100))

ggplot(data) +
  geom_point(aes(x = x, y = y),
    fill = "grey",
    size = 10, alpha = 0.7, stroke = 0
  ) +
  theme_classic()
```

[image]

```r
ggplot(data) +
  geom_point(aes(x = x, y = y),
    fill = "grey", size = 10, alpha = 0.7,
    shape = 21, stroke = 0
  ) +
  theme_classic()
```

[image]