# ggplot guide_legend argument changes continuous legend to discrete

Tags: r, ggplot2

Using the `guide_legend` argument, even without specifiying any further arguments, changes my legend from a continuous legend to a discrete one. 
I need to correct this (e.g. to use this: [Add a box for the NA values to the ggplot legend for a continous map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42365483/add-a-box-for-the-na-values-to-the-ggplot-legend-for-a-continous-map/42380983#42380983) and then order the legends.)

```
df <- expand.grid(X1 = 1:10, X2 = 1:10)
df$value <- df$X1 * df$X2

ggplot(df, aes(X1, X2)) + 
  geom_tile(aes(fill = value))
```

[image: The Legend on the right side is continuous]

```
ggplot(df, aes(X1, X2)) + 
  geom_tile(aes(fill = value))+
  scale_fill_continuous(guide = guide_legend())
```

[image: The legend now is discrete]

The same happens, if I specify the argument when adding it as a `+ guides(fill = guide_legend())`

Any ideas how to make sure the legend stays unchanged, so that I can use e.g. the `order` argument.

Thanks!

Comment: try ```guide_colourbar()``` instead of ```guide_legend()```

Comment: "Working as intended" here: `guide_legend()` is used for [discrete scales](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/guide_legend.html), whereas `guide_colorbar()` is the version to use for [continuous scales](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/guide_colourbar.html).  They should both all accept the same/similar list of arguments, such as `order=`....

Comment: Fantastic, many thanks to both of you! This does the trick. The naming seems odd to me though - the ```guide_legend``` sounds like it would be a general command. Oh well :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Thanks to Ilkyun Im and chemdork123 for providing me with the answers.

The right command here would be `guide_colorbar()`.

So it would be:

```
ggplot(df, aes(X1, X2)) + 
  geom_tile(aes(fill = value))+
  scale_fill_continuous(guide = guide_colorbar())
```

I still find it odd that the `guide_legend()` is not a general command, but specific to discrete legends. Oh well :)