# ggplot - ordering legends with guides changes continuous legend to discrete

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I'm running ggplot2 v3.4.1. I created this 2 legend plot that by default it is placing the `year2` size legend below the `cty` color legend. However, I would like the size legend to be on top.

```
library(tidyverse)

mpg$year2 = factor(mpg$year)
values = c(2,4); names(values) = c("1999", "2008")
p = mpg %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = cty, y = hwy, color = cty, size = year2)) + 
  geom_point() +
  scale_size_manual(name = "year2", values = values)
p
```

[image: continuous]

Therefore, I used `guides()` to specify the legend ordering but it changes the continuous color legend `cty` to discrete

```
p + guides(size = guide_legend(order = 1), 
           color = guide_legend(order = 2))
```

[image: discrete]

I saw this post [ggplot guide_legend argument changes continuous legend to discrete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61355218/ggplot-guide-legend-argument-changes-continuous-legend-to-discrete) but am unable to figure out how to use `guide_colorbar()` when you have 2 or more legends.

How do I change my code to keep the `cty` legend as continuous? Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's simply

```r
p + guides(size = guide_legend(order = 1), 
           color = guide_colorbar(order = 2))
```

[image]

Comment: I didn't realize colorbar was a drop in replacement for guide_legend.  Spent all morning trying to figure this out. Thank you