# show NA values in geom_sf() , group_by

Tags: r, ggplot2, group-by, na, geom-sf

I am trying to report how often a district is showing up in my bride price sample. But I think when a district does't have any reports or NAs, then the frequency == 0 so the district is still being coloured. I want to show districts with NAs as grey coloured. [image]

```
bp_dist1 <- joined1 |>
  group_by(ADM2_EN) |> 
  mutate(freq = n()) |> 
  ggplot() +
  geom_sf(aes(fill = freq), na.rm=T) +
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "coral", high = "coral4") +
  theme(rect = element_blank(), axis.text.x = element_blank(),
        axis.text.y = element_blank(), axis.ticks = element_blank(), 
        axis.title.x = element_blank(), axis.title.y = element_blank()) +
  guides(fill = guide_colourbar(
    title = "Frequency of bride price reports", title.theme = element_text(size = 8),
    label.theme = element_text(size = 7)
    ))
```

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42365483/add-a-box-for-the-na-values-to-the-ggplot-legend-for-a-continuous-map

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to know without the actual data you're using (if you post the data or a reproducible example it's easier to help :)), but I'm almost certain it's a data issue. Try running `any(is.na(freq))` on the dataframe column you're using. I suspect it may come up `FALSE`, indicating that somewhere along the line, your `NA`s were removed or otherwise have been messed up.

If it comes up `TRUE` then you know you do in fact have the `NA` values in your dataframe and it's a plotting issue.

If you do have the `NA`s and it's a plotting issue, try adding the `na.value` argument to `scale_fill_gradient`:

```
library(sf)
# using nc as example dataset
nc <- sf::st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package = "sf"), quiet = TRUE)

# make an integer column with some NA's
nc$var <- sample(
  c(sample(x = c(0:10), size = 94, replace = TRUE), rep(NA, 6))
)

# plot the data
ggplot(nc) +
  geom_sf(aes(fill = var)) + 
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "coral", high = "coral4", na.value = "green") +
  theme_void()
```

[image]

Although, without that `na.value`, `ggplot()` should still recognize the NA's. In my example it looks like this:

[image]