# ggplot2: combined colour and fill legends, legend.key border

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to make a bar chart of numbers, with an overlaid line and confidence interval for the rate. I want the legend to make sense, i.e. one entry for the bars and one for the line and confidence interval.

This is what I've got so far. It's almost perfect, except for the red border around the legend key for the rate. I can't figure out how to remove the border without removing the line too. Am I missing something? Am I going about the whole construction of the legend wrong? I haven't used `scale_xxx_identity()` before and what I'm doing feels like a bit of a hack, so I'm open to other options.

```r
library(tidyverse)

test <- tibble(year = 2001:2010,
               number = 20:29,
               rate = 0.02,
               rate_l = 0.015,
               rate_u = 0.025)

secondAxisFactor <- 500

test %>% 
    ggplot(aes(factor(year), number)) +
    geom_col(aes(fill = "turquoise",
                 colour = "transparent")) +
    geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = rate_l * secondAxisFactor,
                    ymax = rate_u * secondAxisFactor,
                    group = 1,
                    fill = "pink"),
                alpha = 0.8) +
    geom_line(aes(y = rate * secondAxisFactor,
                  group = 1,
                  colour = "red"),
              size = 1) +
    scale_fill_identity(name = NULL,
                        guide = "legend",
                        breaks = c("turquoise", "pink"),
                        labels = c("Number", "Rate (95% CI)")) +
    scale_color_identity(name = NULL,
                         guide = "legend",
                         breaks = c("transparent", "red"),
                         labels = c("Number", "Rate (95% CI)"))
```

[image: first try: red border around colour fill]

I've also tried having a fill legend only for the bars and a colour legend only for the line, and then setting the `legend.key` fill to pink in `theme()`. That also *almost* works, but the pink peeks out from behind the turquoise. Perhaps there's a way to fix that?

```r
test %>% 
    ggplot(aes(factor(year), number)) +
    geom_col(aes(fill = "turquoise")) +  # removed transparent
    geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = rate_l * secondAxisFactor,
                    ymax = rate_u * secondAxisFactor,
                    group = 1),  # pink not in aes()
                fill = "pink",
                alpha = 0.8) +
    geom_line(aes(y = rate * secondAxisFactor,
                  group = 1,
                  colour = "red"),
              size = 1) +
    scale_fill_identity(name = NULL,
                        guide = "legend",
                        # fill legend only for bars
                        breaks = c("turquoise"),
                        labels = c("Number")) +
    scale_color_identity(name = NULL,
                         guide = "legend",
                         # colour legend only for line
                         breaks = c("red"),
                         labels = c("Rate (95% CI)")) +
    # setting legend.key fill to pink
    theme(legend.key = element_rect(fill = "pink"))
```

[image: second try: pink background behind fill legend]

Comment: remove `colour = "transparent"` from the `geom_col` argument. Then the `scale_color_identity` is also not needed.

Comment: @Jimbou That's the way I had it first, but then the legend gets split into two legends (colour and fill).

Comment: @Oliver: maybe you can try this trick https://stackoverflow.com/a/49377292/786542

Comment: @Tung that doesn't do what I want unfortunately, I want the legend items for the line and the ribbon to be combined