# How to add an extra legend to plot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend, geom

I have a plot made with ggplot and I would like to add an "extra" legend there. I tried to do this "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16389636/in-ggplot2-how-can-i-add-additional-legend" but I did not manage to get it right. I also tried annotating it, but that squished the plot itself.

So what I would like to do is to add legends with a corresponding color and a text for the darkorange and darker blue small confidence intervals, that are on top of the bigger bars. In the real plot I have eight error bars on every "point" of the flipped x-axis that represent a question/statement, also the small "National average" differs in that it is not always parallel to the top of the big bars.I have tried to mess with the color and fill manuals, annotate it and add new geom_point, but I could not get those to work. Any ideas or tips that I could do? Thank you.

Here is the example plot:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RdTTS.png)

Here is an example code:

```
plot_data <- expand.grid(
    Arviointi = c("First Assessment", "Second Assessment"),
    Mittari = c("happy_share", "lonely_share", "self_satisfaction_share", "enjoyment_share")
)
plot_data <- plot_data %>%
    mutate(value = runif(n(), 0.15, 0.85))

# Modify variable names and labels
custom_labels <- c("statement1", "statement2", "question3?", "question4?")
ss <- data.frame(
    Mittari = unique(plot_data$Mittari),
    vastaukset = c("Agree/Strongly agree", "Yes", "Yes", "Often/Very often")
)

# Merge data frames
plot_data <- plot_data %>%
    left_join(ss, by = "Mittari")

plot_data <- plot_data %>%
    mutate(facet = case_when(
        Mittari %in% c("happy_share", "lonely_share") ~ "Based on Teacher Assessments",
        Mittari %in% c("enjoyment_share", "self_satisfaction_share") ~ "Based on Child Self-Assessments"
    ))

# Create the plot
ggplot(plot_data, aes(x = Mittari, y = value, fill = Arviointi)) +
    geom_col(position = position_dodge2(reverse = TRUE), width = 0.45, alpha = 0.85) +
    geom_vline(aes(xintercept = 0, color = 'National Average')) +
    geom_text(aes(group = Mittari, y = 0.35, label = vastaukset), size = 3.4, hjust = 0.5, vjust = -2.1, colour = "grey8") +
    geom_errorbar(
        data = subset(plot_data, Mittari == "happy_share" & Arviointi == "First Assessment"),
        aes(x = Mittari, ymin = value - 0.05, ymax = value + 0.09, width = 0),
        position = position_nudge(x = 0.1125),
        color = "steelblue4",
        size = 1.5,
    ) +
    geom_errorbar(
        data = subset(plot_data, Mittari == "happy_share" & Arviointi == "Second Assessment"),
        aes(x = Mittari, ymin = value - 0.08, ymax = value + 0.04, width = 0),
        position = position_nudge(x = -0.1125),
        color = "darkorange3",
        size = 1.5,
    ) +
    geom_errorbar(data = plot_data, aes(x = Mittari, ymin = value, ymax = value, group = Arviointi, width = 0.45), position = position_dodge2(reverse = TRUE)) +
    scale_fill_manual(values = c("First Assessment" = "steelblue", "Second Assessment" = "darkorange")) +
    scale_color_manual(values = c("black")) +
    facet_grid(facet ~., scales = "free_y", space = "free_y", switch = "y") +
    theme_minimal(base_family = "Arial") +
    coord_flip() +
    scale_y_continuous(
        labels = scales::percent_format(scale = 100),
        breaks = seq(0, 1, by = 0.1),
        minor_breaks = NULL,
        limits = c(0, 1)
    ) +
    scale_x_discrete(breaks = c("happy_share", "lonely_share", "self_satisfaction_share", "enjoyment_share"), labels = custom_labels) +
    labs(y = NULL, x = NULL, color = NULL) +
    guides(fill = guide_legend(order = 1), color = guide_legend(order = 2)) +
    theme(legend.title = element_blank(), legend.text = element_text(size = 10.5)) +
    theme(legend.spacing.y = unit(-0.1, "cm")) +
    theme(panel.spacing = unit(3, "lines")) +
    theme(strip.text.y.left = element_blank())
```

Comment: If you want a legend, you need to color the error bars by mapping color to a variable inside `aes` - try `color = Arviointi` inside the `aes` of `geom_errorbar` and remove the color _outside_ the `aes

Comment: Thanks @AllanCameron , that was very helpful. Now the problem I face is that the black vline I used to create the legend for the National Average also "goes through" the new legends of the confidence intervals, or that it is a similar horizontal bar and not a thin black line.