# Drawing ggplot with different line colour and point shapes

Tags: r, ggplot2

I tried to draw a `ggplot` with below data and aesthetics

```
  library(ggplot2)
  mydata = rbind(data.frame('date' = as.Date(c('2010-01-01', '2011-01-01', '2012-01-01')), var1 = c('A', 'A', 'A'), var2 = c('X', 'X', 'X'), val = c(10, 3, 10)),
            data.frame('date' = as.Date(c('2010-01-01', '2011-01-01', '2012-01-01')), var1 = c('B', 'B', 'B'), var2 = c('X', 'X', 'X'), val = c(10+2, 3+2, 10+2)),
            data.frame('date' = as.Date(c('2010-01-01', '2011-01-01', '2012-01-01')), var1 = c('A', 'A', 'A'), var2 = c('Y', 'Y', 'Y'), val = c(10-2, 3-2, 10-2)),
            data.frame('date' = as.Date(c('2010-01-01', '2011-01-01', '2012-01-01')), var1 = c('B', 'B', 'B'), var2 = c('Y', 'Y', 'Y'), val = c(10+5, 3+5, 10+5)))

ggplot(data = mydata, aes(x = date)) +
    geom_line(aes(y = val, color = var1)) +
    geom_point(aes(y = val, color = var1, shape = var2))
```

This approach is generating a strange plot. I wanted to draw 4 different lines on same `date` in x-axis, where `var1` to be distinguished by colour and `var2` to be distinguished by point shape.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to give `geom_line` some way to tell which points to connect. `color = var1` is all it has, so it is connecting all points with the same `var1` values. You want a separate line for each group defined by `var1` AND `var2`, so we combine those and give it to the `group` aesthetic:

```
ggplot(data = mydata, aes(x = date)) +
    geom_line(aes(y = val, color = var1, group = paste(var1, var2))) +
    geom_point(aes(y = val, color = var1, shape = var2)) + 
    guides(color = guide_legend(override.aes = list(shape = NA)))
```

[image]

Comment: This is indeed correct. Just one thing though, is it possible to remove the shape information from the legend of `var1`? This is because, the shape information e.g. `circle` is present for both colours viz 'red' and `blue` - so it is a bit misleading

Comment: Yeah, [here's the FAQ on that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16529687/903061). I'll edit it in.

Answer (score 2):

You can move your point and line aesthetic mappings to the global mapping:

```
ggplot(data = mydata, aes(x = date, y=val, color=var1, shape=var2)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point() + 
  # as shown by @Gregor Thomas solution below
  guides(color = guide_legend(override.aes = list(shape = NA)))
```

[image: global_mapping]