# How to place legend from individual line data

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm a bit confused how to plot a legend from individual data instead of group of a group of data. Any idea how I can build and add a beautiful legend on the top right position?

```
ano=c(1986, 1990, 1994, 1998, 2002, 2006, 2010)

reapresentacao = c(.66, .70, .72, .75, .78, NA, NA)
retencao = c(.39, .42, .50, .51, .50, NA,NA)
insucesso = c(.49, .50, .48, .50, .60, NA , NA)
institucionalizacao <- data.frame(ano, retencao, reapresentacao,insucesso)


p <-qplot(xlab="Eleições", ylab="Taxa de reapresentação, \n retenção e insucesso")
p <- p + geom_point(aes(x=institucionalizacao$ano, y=institucionalizacao$retencao), size =     I(8), colour = "grey10")
p <- p + geom_line(aes(x=institucionalizacao$ano, y=institucionalizacao$retencao), size =  I(5), colour = "grey10")
p <- p + geom_point(aes(x=institucionalizacao$ano, y=institucionalizacao$reapresentacao), size = I(8), colour = "grey45")
p <- p + geom_line(aes(x=institucionalizacao$ano, y=institucionalizacao$reapresentacao), size = I(5), colour = "grey45")
p <- p + geom_point(aes(x=institucionalizacao$ano, y=institucionalizacao$insucesso), size = I(8), colour = "grey75")
p <- p + geom_line(aes(x=institucionalizacao$ano, y=institucionalizacao$insucesso), size = I(5), colour = "grey75")
p <- p + theme_minimal(base_size = 18, base_family = "")
p <- p + scale_y_continuous(limits=RangeY, breaks=YBreaks, labels=YTickLabels, expand=c(0,0))
p <- p + scale_x_continuous(breaks = round(seq(min(institucionalizacao$ano), max(institucionalizacao$ano), by = 4),1))
print(p)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Add legend to ggplot2 line plot](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10349206/add-legend-to-ggplot2-line-plot)

Answer (score 1):

From what I can gather from other answers to similar questions (such as [this one...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18060116/adding-legend-to-ggplot-when-lines-were-added-manually)) You need to assign the colour inside aes(), but you also need to be linking to a data frame. The way I achieved what you asked for was to reshape your data frame using `melt` from the `reshape2` package. That way you can have your three different variables that you are tracking over the years assigned to given year.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)
ano=c(1986, 1990, 1994, 1998, 2002, 2006, 2010)

reapresentacao = c(.66, .70, .72, .75, .78, NA, NA)
retencao = c(.39, .42, .50, .51, .50, NA,NA)
insucesso = c(.49, .50, .48, .50, .60, NA , NA)
group = c("reapresentacao","retencao","insucesso")
institucionalizacao <- data.frame(ano, retencao, reapresentacao,insucesso,)


# Using the reshape2 package you can reorganize your dataframe so that you can organiz
newdf = melt(institucionalizacao, id = c("ano"), measure.vars = c("reapresentacao","retencao","insucesso"),
             variable.name = "group", value.name = "value")
```

Now you can use the structure of the new data frame to make it easier to plot your data. `ggplot` will assign colors automatically which then you can then personalize using `scale_color_manual`.

```
p <- ggplot() + 
  geom_point(data = newdf, aes(x=ano, y=value, colour = variable ), size = I(3)) +
  geom_line(data = newdf, aes(x=ano, y=value, colour = variable), size = I(1)) +
  labs(list(x="Eleições",y="Taxa")) +
  theme_minimal(base_size = 12, base_family = "") 
p
```

[image: ggplot1]

Manually change the colour of the scale by assigning the colours to the group names and label the legend.

```
  p + scale_color_manual(name  ="Change group name",
                         values=c("retencao"=        "grey10", 
                                  "reapresentacao"=  "grey45",
                                  "insucesso"=       "grey75"))
```

[image: ggplot2]

Comment: @Paulo Thank you for adding the figures. Any reason in particular that you preferred to use labs(list(x=,y=)) instead of xlab(c("")) + ylab(c("")).