# insert graph legend using ggplot

Tags: r, graph, ggplot2, legend

I have a question regarding the use of ggplot. I have the following data.frame, and a constant. I'm using the following function and I managed to make my plot but I can not print the legend, what am I doing wrong?

this function would I use to get the plot:

```
LINER_GRAPH_POWER_LIST_VALUES<-function(DF_N_EPC_AND_FOUND_EPC, DF_READ_EXTERNAL_LIST_EPC_TAGS ){
  require(ggplot2)
  ggplot(DF_N_EPC_AND_FOUND_EPC, aes(x=power_value, y=total_epc), colour = variables) +
  geom_line(color="red") +
  geom_point(color="red", shape=20) +
  geom_line(aes(x=power_value, y=found_epc), color="blue") +
  geom_point(aes(x=power_value, y=found_epc), color="blue", shape=20) +
  geom_hline(yintercept=nrow(DF_READ_EXTERNAL_LIST_EPC_TAGS), color="green")+
  scale_colour_manual(values = c("total_epc"="red","epc_found"="blue", "num_of_list_reference_tags"="green"))
}
```

the plot
[image]

And the data.frame -> DF_N_EPC_AND_FOUND_EPC

```
    power_value total_epc   found_epc
1   31.5    9   5
2   31.0    7   4
3   30.5    6   4
4   30.0    7   4
5   29.5    8   5
6   29.0    9   5
7   28.5    8   5
8   28.0    9   5
9   27.5    8   4
10  27.0    7   4
11  26.5    8   5
12  26.0    7   5
13  25.5    5   4
14  25.0    5   4
15  24.5    5   4
16  24.0    4   3
17  23.5    4   3
18  23.0    4   3
19  22.5    4   3
20  22.0    4   3
```

I'm using scale_colour_manual, as you can see, but the legend of the graph does not appear

Comment: Can you share `dput(DF_N_EPC_AND_FOUND_EPC)` to make this easy to reproduce?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/10349206/324364

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to do that, you will have to transform your data from wide to long format.

```
# reading the data
df <- read.table(text="nr    power_value total_epc   found_epc
1   31.5    9   5
2   31.0    7   4
3   30.5    6   4
4   30.0    7   4
5   29.5    8   5
6   29.0    9   5
7   28.5    8   5
8   28.0    9   5
9   27.5    8   4
10  27.0    7   4
11  26.5    8   5
12  26.0    7   5
13  25.5    5   4
14  25.0    5   4
15  24.5    5   4
16  24.0    4   3
17  23.5    4   3
18  23.0    4   3
19  22.5    4   3
20  22.0    4   3", header=TRUE)

# from wide to long format
require(reshape2)
df.m <- melt(df, id=c("power_value","nr"), measure=c("total_epc","found_epc"), variable.name="epc")

# creating the plot
ggplot(df.m, aes(x=power_value, y=value, color=epc)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point() +
  geom_hline(yintercept=6, color="green")
```

the result:
[image]

Comment: +1, though note that this *can* be done manually as seen [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10349206/add-legend-to-ggplot2-line-plot)

Comment: @DavidRobinson Thanx, it's a nice tric. However, I do prefer this above a manual solution.