# ggplot legend not showing up in lift chart

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I'm trying to get a legend to show up in a left chart I've developed.  It's not showing up.  I've checked [ggplot legend not working with scale_colour_manual](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33768613/ggplot-legend-not-working-with-scale-colour-manual) as well as [How to add a legend in ggplot (not showing up)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27035357/how-to-add-a-legend-in-ggplot-not-showing-up) to no avail.

Here is some sample data:

```
#x axis values
deciles <- c(1:10)
#model_1
decile_act_pp <- c(393.6773, 243.0795, 250.2033, 220.0076, 180.7292,
               187.3803,208.8504,162.9708,140.9405,107.7656)
#model_2
model2_pp_norm <- c(537.9617, 306.0807, 244.6228, 207.8051, 181.8801,
161.3744,142.8224,125.3262,107.5905,  80.13438)
#model_3
model1_pp_norm <- c(515.9927,297.8425, 240.8723, 206.6129, 183.6805, 
164.3337, 148.4509,134.1227, 115.0055, 88.68549)
#combine to make a chart
df <- as.data.frame(cbind(deciles, decile_act_pp, model2_pp_norm, 
model1_pp_norm))

#develop the chart

ggplot(data = df, aes(x = as.factor(deciles), group = 1)) +
geom_point(aes(y = decile_act_pp), color = "blue") +
geom_line(aes(y = decile_act_pp), color = "blue") +
geom_point(aes(y = model2_pp_norm), color = "red") +
geom_line(aes(y = model2_pp_norm), color = "red") +
geom_point(aes(y = model1_pp_norm), color = "green") +
geom_line(aes(y = model1_pp_norm), color = "green") +
xlab("Deciles") +
labs(colour="Datasets",x="Deciles",y="Pure Premium") +
scale_color_manual('', limits = c('decile_act_pp', 'model2_pp_norm', 
'model1_pp_norm'), values = c("blue", "red", "green"))
```

The chart look exactly as I want it minus missing the legend.  Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Yes, figure looks exactly like you want, but it's not plotted in the right way and that's why you don't get the legend. Check [this possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3427457/ggplot-and-r-two-variables-over-time)

Comment: Why would you expect a legend to be printed if you map nothing to color, shape or size?

Comment: In ggplot, you get a legend by mapping a data column to, say, `color` *inside* `aes`. In your plot, you've hard-coded the color for each line outside of `aes`. Your data frame is currently in "wide" format. Instead, stack your model data frames into a single data frame with a new column marking the model each row of data refers to, and map color to that new column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
library(reshape2) 
df2 <- melt(data = df, id.vars = 1)
ggplot(data = df2, aes(x = as.factor(deciles), group = 1)) + geom_point(aes( y=value, color = variable)) + geom_line(aes(y = value, group = variable, color = variable))
```

Comment: Please include all extra packages that you used