# Why don't I get a legend and colours in my ggplot?

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, legend

This is my minimal working example:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

n = 200
p = 10

df <- data.frame(
  x = 1:n/p,
  y = 2*sin(1:n/p) + 1:n/p + runif(n)) %>%
    mutate(a = rep(sum(y)/length(x), n))

ggplot(df, aes(x = x)) +
  geom_line(aes(y = y, fill = "LINE1")) +
  geom_line(aes(y = a, fill = "LINE2")) +
  geom_abline(aes(fill = "LINE3")) +
  theme_classic() +
  scale_colour_manual(values = c(
    "LINE1" = "red",
    "LINE2" = "blue",
    "LINE3" = "orange"))
```

[image]

Although I do get a plot, it does not have a legend. I also don't get colours. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Use `color` not `fill` for line colors. `fill` is for areas (bars, ribbons, etc.).

Comment: As to why you don't have a legend, it's because you're not mapping your color aesthetic to a single data column and using one `geom_line` call. You will need to reshape your data into long format using `reshape2::melt` or `tidyr::gather`. This is a commonly asked R-faq, duplicate here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/10349206/903061