# Adding legends to two variable line graph - ggplot2 R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataframe named data with index, mean and median as variables. I have created the graph with this code.

```
ggplot(data, aes(x = index)) + 
  geom_line(aes(y = median), size = 1, colour="firebrick") + 
  geom_line(aes(y = mean), size = 1, colour = "dodgerblue4") + geom_point(size = 2, aes(y = median), colour = 'firebrick' ) +  
  geom_point(size = 2, aes(y = mean), colour = 'dodgerblue4' )
```

I want to add legend to this graph for median and mean. I am able to find legends only for factor of single variable. But not able to do it for two variables.

I am trying this,

```
scale_colour_manual("", breaks = c("Median", "Mean"),values = c("firebrick", "dodgerblue4"))
```

But no effect in the graph.  Can anybody help me in doing this?

Thanks

Comment: @aosmith I saw the melt option already. But it was too complicated for my kind of requirement. So is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Then isn't the accepted answer exactly what you want?  Did you see that `colour` was inside `aes`?  [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10355844/2461552) is another duplicate.