# R : How to plot two different kind of plot with ggplot2?

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

My data is like this :

```
id <- c('a','a','b','b')
var <- c('Var1','Var2','Var1','Var2')
value <- c(123,421,2132,633)
df <- cbind(id,var,value)
```

I would like to plot a scatter plot of *Var1* and a bar chart of *Var2*, with a legend showing that the dot is *Var1* and the Bar is *Var2*

I have tried these code :

```
g <- ggplot(data = df, aes(x=id, y=value, fill=var)
g + stat_identity(geom = c("point","bar"))
```

But both *Var1* and *Var2* are showed in scatter point in this way.

I also tried to create two seprate data for *Var1* and *Var2*.

```
id = c('a','b')
Var1 = c(123,2132)
Var2 = c(421,633)
df1 = cbind.data.frame(id, Var1)
df2 = cbind.data.frame(id, Var2)

g <- ggplot()
g + geom_point(data = df1, aes(x=id, y=Var1),stat = "identity")) +
    geom_bar(data = df2, aes(x=id, y=Var2),stat = "identity"))
```

In this way, I can combine a scatter point with a bar chart, but there is no legend and I don't know how to make the legend telling readers that the dot is *Var1* and the bar is *Var2*

Comment: please use `cbind.data.frame` instead of `cbind`

Comment: Have you realy applied the example code that you are giving? I am asking because the both appraoches generate data of class matrix, which cannot be used directlyin ggplot. Also, the ggplot in the second approach does not work, because you close to many brackets. Lastly, have you checked other threads on SO, such as [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10349206/add-legend-to-ggplot2-line-plot) one

Comment: indeed i don't think you can do it without splitting the data (outside or inside  ggplot)

Answer (score 1):

First off, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10349206/add-legend-to-ggplot2-line-plot). Thanks @Daniel!

You could try this:

```
id = c('a','b')
Var1 = c(123,2132)
Var2 = c(421,633)
df1 = cbind.data.frame(id, Var1)
df2 = cbind.data.frame(id, Var2)
library(ggplot2)
g <- ggplot()
g + geom_bar(data = df2, aes(x=id, y=Var2, fill = 'Var2'),stat = "identity")+
     geom_point(data = df1, aes(x=id, y=Var1, colour = 'Var1'),stat = "identity", size = 2) +
    scale_fill_manual(values = c('Var2' = 'blue'), name = 'Bars')+
    scale_colour_manual(values = c('Var1' = 'red'), name = 'Dots')
```

[image]

Basically, we use the `aes` within `geom_point` and `geom_bar` to define our color or fill. Then use `scale_*_manual` to control display. Also, we call `geom_bar` **before** `geom_point` so that the dots are plotted **over** the bar. Also, I use `size = 2` in `geom_point` so that the point is a little more distinguishable.

Comment: I would just add the link to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10349206/add-legend-to-ggplot2-line-plot) question, where different variants are explained for a line plot.