# How to add a legend on a multiple line graph in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, line, legend

I am trying to plot two different datasets on the same plot. I am using this code to add the lines and to actually plot everything

```
ggplot()+
geom_point(data=Acc, aes(x=Year, y=Accumulo), color="lightskyblue")+
geom_line(data=Acc, aes(x=Year, y=RM3), color="gold1")+
geom_line(data=Acc, aes(x=Year, y=RM5), color="springgreen3")+
geom_line(data=Acc, aes(x=Year, y=RM50), color="blue")+
geom_line(data=Vulcani, aes(x=Year, y=Accumulo.V), color="red")+
theme_bw()+
scale_x_continuous(expand=expand_scale(0)) + scale_y_continuous(limits=c(50,350),expand=expand_scale(0))
```

but I can't find any way to add a legend and add custom labels to the different series. I find a way to add legends on a single dataset, but I can't find a way to add to this one a legend on the side

Comment: a basic example for Acc and Vulcani would help us reproduce the problem

Comment: Looks like a duplicate [Adding legends to multiple line plots with ggplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39201856/adding-legends-to-multiple-line-plots-with-ggplot)

Comment: Feel free to add an extract of your datasets with `dput(Acc)` and `dput(Vulcani)` to your question to allow a more precise answer

Answer (score 1):

You are better off creating a single dataset tailored to your plot needs before, which would be in the long format, so that you can give a single `geom_line()` instruction, and add colors to the lines with `aes(color = ...)` within the call to `geom_line()`. Here's an example with the `midwest` dataset (consider them as distinct datasets for the sake of example)

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

long_midwest <- midwest %>% 
    select(popwhite, popasian, PID, poptotal) %>% 
    gather(key = "variable", value = "value", -PID, -poptotal) # convert to long format

long_midwest2 <- midwest %>% 
    select(poptotal, perchsd, PID) %>% 
    gather(key = "variable", value = "value", -PID, -poptotal)

plot_data <- bind_rows(long_midwest, long_midwest2) %>% # bind datasets vertically
    mutate(line_type = ifelse(variable == 'perchsd', 'A', 'B')) # creates a line_type variable

ggplot(data = plot_data, aes(x=poptotal, y = value))+
    geom_line(aes(color = variable, linetype = line_type)) +
    scale_color_manual(
        values = c('lightskyblue', 'gold1', 'blue'),
        name = "My color legend"
    ) +
    scale_linetype_manual(
        values = c(3, 1), # play with the numbers to get the correct styling
        name = "My linetype legend"
    )
```

[image]

I added a `line_type` variable to show the most generic case where you want specific mapping between the column values and the line type. If it is the same than, say, `variable`, just use `aes(color = variable, linetype = variable)`. You can then decide which linetype you want ([see here for more details](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/aes_linetype_size_shape.html)).

For customising the labels, just change the content of `variable` within the dataset with the desired values.

Comment: I am trying to do use this example as a reference, but as far as I understand, the dataset you are binding together are of the same length and will use the same x axis (correct me if I'm wrong)... I haven't specified this in my post bc I didn't think it was a key part of the solution, but the two dataset I have have two different series for the x axis (they are still plotted over the same variable, but with different values

Comment: `bind_rows` doesn't need to have common x values nor the same number of rows, it is a simple row binding. It does need columns from both datasets to have the same names, though. Just be sure that your x series from both datasets are of the same type (double or numeric I guess)

Comment: Ok, I'll try it! And yes, I need to have both dots and lines in the graph... when you say adding a line_type variable to the dataset ... what do you mean by it exactly? I'm sorry, but I am new to R

Comment: I've edited my answer to add a line type specification within the `aes()` call. Using `linetype` within an `aes()` call means you're mapping the style of the graph lines to the values of a variable in your dataset (that's what *is* an aesthetic in `ggplot2`).

Also remember that differenciating the line types *should* have a meaning besides the visual impact and the meaning already given by colors, that's why I kept the second legend in the example plot.