# Adding legend to a multi-histogram ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to add a legend to a `ggplot` of two histograms, that may overlap and therefore would like to have them slightly transparent:

```
library(ggplot2)
set.seed(1)
plot.df <- data.frame(x=c(rnorm(1000,30,1),rnorm(10000,40,5)),
                      group=c(rep("a",1000),rep("b",10000)))
```

using:

```
ggplot(plot.df,aes(x=x,fill=factor(group)))+ 
  geom_histogram(data=subset(plot.df,group=='a'),fill="red",alpha=0.5)+
  geom_histogram(data=subset(plot.df,group=='b'),fill="darkgray",alpha=0.5)+
  scale_colour_manual(name="group",values=c("red","darkgray"),labels=c("a","b"))+scale_fill_manual(name="group",values=c("red","darkgray"),labels=c("a","b"))
```

but all I get is:

[image]

What's missing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instead of plotting the two hisgrams separately, you can specify the `fill` parameter in the mapping as the `group` variable, in which case the legend will be automatically generated.

```
ggplot(plot.df, aes(x=x, fill = group)) + 
  geom_histogram(alpha = 0.5) + 
  scale_fill_manual(name="group",values=c("red","darkgray"),labels=c("a","b"))
```

[image]

Borrowed from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10349206/add-legend-to-ggplot2-line-plot), the trick lies in setting up the `fill` parameter in the **mapping**(i.e `aes` here) of each of the `histogram` plot and then you can use `scale_fill_manual` normally:

```
ggplot(plot.df,aes(x=x))+ 
    geom_histogram(data=subset(plot.df,group=='a'),aes(fill=group),alpha=0.5)+
    geom_histogram(data=subset(plot.df,group=='b'),aes(fill=group),alpha=0.5)+
    scale_fill_manual(name="group", values=c("red","darkgray"),labels=c("a","b"))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. However, that ggplot code doesn't make the histograms transparent. I updated my question to make this point clearer.

Comment: Updated the answer. You need to wrap the `fill` parameter in the `aes` in order for `ggplot` to recognize and generate the legend for you.