# How to add a legend in ggplot2 when using 3 geom_point arguments?

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I got an issue if i want to add a legend in ggplot2 when using the next code:

```
ggplot() +
   geom_point(data = select, aes(x = Date, y = Netto), colour = "red") +
   geom_point(data = select, aes(x = Date, y = First), colour = "blue") +
   geom_point(data = select, aes(x = Date, y = Second), colour = "black")
```

I got three different colors, but I can't find how to add a legend in this plot.

[image: A plot of the code]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10349375/5316882

Comment: Keep it ggplot-like and use just one geom with data in long format. Something like `tidyr::gather(select, key = key, value = value, Netto, First, Second) %>% ggplot(aes(x = Date, y = value, color = key)) + geom_point()`