# Legend in ggplot2 when separately added elements

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I'd like to add a ggplot legend when we have separately added elements.

I'm aware of previous answers to this question, but for some reason I haven't been able to sort out my issue ([Add legend to ggplot2 line plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10349206/add-legend-to-ggplot2-line-plot/10349375#10349375)). Thanks!

## Fake data

```
library(ggplot2)
Month <- c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 8, 
           8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 10, 10, 10, 11, 11, 11, 12, 12, 12)
RR <- c(81.30271, 56.97511, 88.95428, 78.43363, 51.39398, 83.53967, 
        95.21302, 63.74089, 94.27137, 92.36272, 69.30449, 100.34571, 
        128.52172, 89.84833, 133.61527, 128.23847, 91.21498, 145.45016,
        124.72499, 85.96523, 153.82113, 123.22878, 97.14116, 154.57004, 
        111.59289, 83.26763, 105.47873, 95.55557, 88.77395, 87.31212, 
        93.03579, 65.35055, 93.22413, 103.43140, 70.40292, 91.58487)
MI <- c(66.729379, 41.891775, 52.137614, 59.376967, 30.717318, 49.339675, 
        62.469691, 25.667561, 60.211374, 48.902722, 18.764486, 65.565712, 
        69.985054, 27.418330, 89.231939, 55.685138, 11.484980, 90.666826,
        44.101654, -8.448102, 87.637798, 55.978782, 15.431156, 92.310042, 
        69.596228, 34.897628, 56.505393, 69.008904, 61.627285, 36.935451, 
        76.392457, 47.493886, 53.750796, 88.204738, 54.806257, 54.358201)
PE <- c(14.57333, 15.08333, 36.81667, 19.05667, 20.67667, 34.20000, 32.74333, 
        38.07333, 34.06000, 43.46000, 50.54000, 34.78000, 58.53667, 62.43000, 
        44.38333, 72.55333, 79.73000, 54.78333, 80.62333, 94.41333, 66.18333, 
        67.25000, 81.71000, 62.26000, 41.99667, 48.37000, 48.97333, 26.54667, 
        27.14667, 50.37667, 16.64333, 17.85667, 39.47333, 15.22667, 15.59667, 
        37.22667)
tt <- data.frame(Month, RR, MI, PE)
```

## What I've done without sucess

```
ggplot(data = tt,
       aes(x = factor(Month))) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(y = RR, x = factor(Month)),
               fill = "dodgerblue4", colour = "dodgerblue4",
               alpha = 0.6) +
  stat_summary(aes(y = RR, x = Month), 
               fun.y = mean, 
               geom = "smooth",
               colour = "dodgerblue4") +

  geom_boxplot(aes(y = MI, group = Month),
               fill = "dimgray", colour = "dimgray",
               alpha = 0.6) +
  stat_summary(aes(y = MI, x = Month), 
               fun.y = mean, 
               geom = "smooth",
               colour = "dimgray") +

  geom_boxplot(aes(y = PE, group = Month),
               fill = "firebrick", colour = "firebrick",
               alpha = 0.6) +
  stat_summary(aes(y = PE, x = Month), 
               fun.y = mean, 
               geom = "smooth",
               colour = "firebrick") +
  labs(x = "Months",
       y = "Flux, mm") +

  scale_fill_manual("",
                    breaks = c("dodgerblue4", "dimgray", "firebrick"),
                    labels = c("dodgerblue4", "dimgray", "firebrick")) +
  theme_bw(base_size = 18)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fix your code with help of the a `named` vector to define color. Make sure to use color from `named` vector with in scope of `aes` for each element.

One of such option can be as:

```
# Named vector for color
lineColors <- c("RR" = "dodgerblue4", "MI" = "dimgray", "PE" = "firebrick")

ggplot(data = tt,
       aes(x = factor(Month))) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(y = RR, x = factor(Month), fill = "RR"),
               colour = "dodgerblue4",
               alpha = 0.6) +
  stat_summary(aes(y = RR, x = Month, colour = "RR"), 
               fun.y = mean, 
               geom = "smooth") +

  geom_boxplot(aes(y = MI, group = Month, fill = "MI"),
               colour = "dimgray",
               alpha = 0.6) +
  stat_summary(aes(y = MI, x = Month, colour = "MI"), 
               fun.y = mean, 
               geom = "smooth"
               ) +

  geom_boxplot(aes(y = PE, group = Month, fill = "PE"),
               colour = "firebrick",
               alpha = 0.6) +
  stat_summary(aes(y = PE, x = Month, colour = "PE"), 
               fun.y = mean, 
               geom = "smooth"
               ) +
  labs(x = "Months",
       y = "Flux, mm") +

  scale_colour_manual(name = "Type", values = lineColors) +
  scale_fill_manual(name = "Type", values = lineColors) +
  theme_bw(base_size = 18)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

A more standard `ggplot` way, where data is provided in a long format. The boxes are dodged and overplotting is thereby avoided.

```
cols <- c("dimgray", "firebrick", "dodgerblue4")

ggplot(data.table::melt(setDT(tt), id = "Month", variable.factor = FALSE), aes(x = Month, y = value)) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(group = interaction(Month, variable),
               fill = variable), alpha = 0.6) +
  stat_summary(aes(color = variable), fun.y = mean, 
               geom = "smooth") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = cols) +
  scale_color_manual(values = cols) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = 1:12)
```

[image]