# How to add label for each multiple plot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, label, legend

```
p = ggplot() + 
  geom_line(data = Month_time, aes(x = Month, y = CarrierDelay), color = "red") +
  geom_line(data = Month_time, aes(x = Month, y = WeatherDelay), color = "purple") +
  geom_line(data = Month_time, aes(x = Month, y = NASDelay), color = "yellow") +
  geom_line(data = Month_time, aes(x = Month, y = SecurityDelay), color = "green") +
  geom_line(data = Month_time, aes(x = Month, y = LateAircraftDelay), color = "blue") +
  xlab('Month') +
  ylab('Delay Types [min]')
print(p)
```

[image: graph picture]
How to add label or legend for each multiple plot?

Comment: see my answer in your previous post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59003622/how-do-you-change-the-x-axis-number/59003680#59003680

Comment: @dc37 Error in scale_x_continous(breaks = 1:12) : 
  could not find function "scale_x_continous"

Comment: `continuous`, I'm editing my code

Comment: @dc37 OMG Thanks a lot it worked now!!

Comment: @dc37 Okay Thanks again!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you change the X axis number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59003622/how-do-you-change-the-x-axis-number)