# How to add a color legend to a ggplot with different geom layers?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have this dataframe that I made. The columnnames are the years. Let's say you have this dataframe, named fruits:

```
      apples | bananas | apples

2012 | 23 | 32 | 23

2013 | 26 | 29 | 23

2014 | 32 | 43 | 25

2015 | 23 | 43 | 26

2016 | 21 | 46 | 22
```

How do you make a line graph out of this? I assume the best way is to use ggplot. I used the following code:

```
years = seq(from = 2012, to = 2016)

ggplot(data = fruits, mapping = aes(x = years)) +
  geom_line(aes(y = apples), color = "green")+
  geom_line(aes(y = bananas), color = "yellow")+
  geom_line(aes(y = apples), color = "indianred")
```

This gives me a plot without a legend. When I search on the internet, I only find examples of graphs that give a legend right away. Is something wrong with my code? And is there a faster way or a way that isn't as hardcoded to have multiple lines in a graph as my way?

Comment: If you want a legend then you have to map on aesthetics, i.e. move `color=..` into `aes()`. To set the colors you have to make use of `scale_color_manual(values = ...)`. See also e.g. Add legend to ggplot2 line plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10349206/add-legend-to-ggplot2-line-plot)

Answer (score 1):

This type of problems generaly has to do with reshaping the data. The format should be the long format and the data is in wide format. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2185252/reshaping-data-frame-from-wide-to-long-format) on how to reshape the data from wide to long format.

Define a colors vector.

```
clrs <- c("green", "yellow", "indianred")
clrs <- setNames(clrs, names(fruits))
```

Since the posted data set has two columns named `"apple"` and R doesn't accept it, the second column with that name becomes `"apple.1"`. The following `sub` will remove the final `".1"` from the second column named `"apple"`.

```
names(fruits)
#[1] "apples"   "bananas"  "apples.1"

sub("\\.\\d$", "", names(clrs))
#[1] "apples"  "bananas" "apples"
```

And now plot it.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

fruits %>%
  tibble::rownames_to_column(var = "years") %>%
  pivot_longer(
    cols = -years,
    names_to = "fruit",
    values_to = "value"
  ) %>%
  mutate(years = as.integer(years)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(years, value, colour = fruit)) +
  geom_line() +
  scale_colour_manual(breaks = names(clrs), values = clrs, 
                      labels = sub("\\.\\d$", "", names(clrs))) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]