# (R) How to get a legend in ggplot2 based on color, linetype and point shape?

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph, tidyverse, legend

How can I get a legend for the following data based to differentiate y1 and y2 based on color, linetype, and shape of points? (sd just means standard deviation)

```
x <- c(2.5, 1.25, 0.625, 0.3125, 0.15625, 0.078, 0.039, 0)

y2<- c(1.422616667,
           1.26845,
           1.149133333,
           0.842166667,
           0.4697,
           0.251566667,
           0.118133333,
           0.000233333)

y1<- c(1.4364,
          1.342333333,
          1.155216667,
          0.88485,
          0.502266667,
          0.2673,
          0.110783333,
          -0.000233333)

sd1<- c(0.12252713,
        0.09232539,
        0.046399526,
        0.078883881,
        0.014853518,
        0.039726687,
        0.012708213,
        0.005837722)

sd2<- c(0.183093342,
        0.122781068,
        0.088565849,
        0.110920994,
        0.036569081,
        0.02125754,
        0.012588791,
        0.002873616)
```

And here's what I've tried:

```
data = data.frame(y1, y2, sd1, sd2, Conc, colors)
colors<- c("y1" = "red", "y2" = "blue")
ggplot(data = data, aes(x = Conc, y = y1))+
  geom_point(aes(x = Conc, y = y1), shape = 15, size = 3)+
  geom_line(aes(x = Conc, y = y1, color = "y1"), linetype = "solid", size = 1.3)+
  geom_line(aes(x = Conc, y = y2, color = "y2"), linetype = "dashed", size = 1.3)+
  geom_point(aes(x = Conc, y = y2), shape = 2, size = 3)+
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin =y1 - sd1, ymax = y1 + sd1), color = "red")+
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = y2 - sd2, ymax = y2 + sd2), color = "blue")+
  labs(x = "Concentration in micg per mL", 
       y = "Absorbance",
       colors = "Legend",
       title = "Absorbance as a function of Concentration")+
  scale_color_manual(values = colors)+
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))+
  theme(plot.title = element_text(face = "bold"))
```

I can get a legend based on line color, but not linetype and shape of point as well. Any ideas?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add legend to ggplot2 line plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10349206/add-legend-to-ggplot2-line-plot)

Comment: your example is not reproducible: your data has column Conc, and colors and you did not provide the values for that column

Answer (score 2):

Sure could you have legends for linetype and shape as well. The easiest way is to first reshape your data into long format, e.g. by putting the data for `y1` and `y2` into separate data frames, adding an id variable and binding these dataframes into one. Doing so you map the `id` variable on `color`, `linetype` and `shape` and you only need one `geom_point`, one `geom_line`, ... to create your plot. The values for linetype and `shape` could be set via `scale_linetype/shape_manual` as you already have done for color. Finally, to merge all legends into one set the same label for each inside `labs` or if you prefer separate legends simply use different labels:

```r
library(ggplot2)

data = list(data.frame(y = y1, sd = sd1, Conc = x, id = "y1"), data.frame(y = y2, sd = sd2, Conc = x, id = "y2"))
data <- do.call("rbind", data)

colors<- c("y1" = "red", "y2" = "blue")
ltys <- c("y1" = "solid", "y2" = "dashed")
shapes <- c("y1" = 15, "y2" = 2)

ggplot(data = data, aes(x = Conc, y = y))+
  geom_point(aes(shape = id), size = 3) +
  geom_line(aes(color = id, linetype = id), size = 1.3) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = y - sd, ymax = y + sd, color = id)) +
  scale_color_manual(values = colors) +
  scale_linetype_manual(values = ltys) +
  scale_shape_manual(values = shapes) +
  labs(x = "Concentration in micg per mL", 
       y = "Absorbance",
       color = "Legend", shape = "Legend", linetype = "Legend",
       title = "Absorbance as a function of Concentration")+
  #scale_color_manual(values = colors)+
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))+
  theme(plot.title = element_text(face = "bold"))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-06-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>