# Getting linetype dashed and color in the legend

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I'm trying to put legent on my ggplot.
I'm strucling to get linetype reflected in the legent.
I have this code:

```
legend_1 <- "a"
legend_2 <- "b"
colours <- t(c('green', 'red'))
colnames(colours) <-c(legend_1, legend_2)

df <- data.frame(a=1:3,b=c(5,6,-1),c=c(3,5,4))
ggplot(df, aes(x=a)) + #byg plot
  geom_line(aes(y=b, color = legend_1), size=1) + #tilføj linje
  geom_line(aes(y=c, color = legend_2), size=1,linetype="dashed")+  #tilføj ny linje

theme_gray() + #tilføj tema
  labs(title = "title", y = 'ppm', x= 'Tid (s)', color = '') + #tilføj titel og akselabels
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) + #centrerer titel
  scale_color_manual(values = colours)
```

[image]

What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically it is identical to adding the color legend. Map on the `linetype` aes instead of setting it as a argument for only one line. Add your desired linetypes via `scale_linetype_manual`, make sure you use the same titles for both legends (I simply remove the titles via `NULL` insidee `labs`):

```r
library(ggplot2)

legend_1 <- "a"
legend_2 <- "b"
colours <- t(c('green', 'red'))
colnames(colours) <-c(legend_1, legend_2)

lty <- c(a = "solid", b = "dashed")

df <- data.frame(a=1:3,b=c(5,6,-1),c=c(3,5,4))
ggplot(df, aes(x=a)) + #byg plot
  geom_line(aes(y=b, color = legend_1, linetype = legend_1), size=1) + #tilføj linje
  geom_line(aes(y=c, color = legend_2, linetype = legend_2), size=1)+  #tilføj ny linje
  theme_gray() + #tilføj tema
  labs(title = "title", y = 'ppm', x= 'Tid (s)', color = NULL, linetype = NULL) + #tilføj titel og akselabels
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) + #centrerer titel
  scale_color_manual(values = colours) +
  scale_linetype_manual(values = lty)
```

[image]

Comment: GREAT - THANKS.
So simple :) 
And I even understand whats happing, LOL

Comment: After reading the code again (which is working :) ) I dont understand how the linetype is read, since the lty is the added to the legent_1:
 `geom_line(aes(y=b, color = legend_1, linetype = legend_1), size=1)`

Comment: Hm. `legend_1` is the name of a variable, which contains the string `"a"`, i.e. under the hood legend_1 is replaced with `"a"`. Instead of letting ggplot2 choose a linetype for "a" we tell ggplot2 via `scale_linetype_manual` that we want to choose our own and via the named vector `lty` we tell ggplot2 which linetype should be assigned to `"a"`.

Comment: I think I understand now - thanks. 
Great help from both of you :)

Answer (score 0):

Stefan's solution is also good, I just wanted to add that it is also possibly to directly set extra aesthetics in the legend by using `guide = guide_legend(override.aes = list(...))`.

```r
library(ggplot2)

legend_1 <- "a"
legend_2 <- "b"
colours <- t(c('green', 'red'))
colnames(colours) <-c(legend_1, legend_2)

df <- data.frame(a=1:3,b=c(5,6,-1),c=c(3,5,4))
ggplot(df, aes(x=a)) + #byg plot
  geom_line(aes(y=b, color = legend_1), size=1) + #tilføj linje
  geom_line(aes(y=c, color = legend_2), size=1,linetype="dashed")+  #tilføj ny linje
  scale_color_manual(
    values = colours,
    guide = guide_legend(override.aes = list(linetype = c("solid", "dashed")))
  ) +
  labs(title = "title", y = 'ppm', x= 'Tid (s)', color = '') + #tilføj titel og akselabels
  theme_gray() + #tilføj tema
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) #centrerer titel
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-07-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Comment: When I get better using ggplot, I might use your solution, but right now I stick to Stefans which seems easier for me to understand. But thanks

Comment: Sure that is reasonable :) Feel free to upvote and accept Stefan's answer if you found it helpful