# Adding legend to a ggplot made from two columns

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, legend

I am plotting residuals from two different methods with the following code:

```
ggplot(df_index, aes(cases100ppl, lm_errors)) +
  geom_point(alpha=1) +
  geom_point(data=df_index, aes(cases100ppl, error), col="red", alpha=0.2)
```

How can I add a legend to this?

the data has a structure like this:

```
code       cases100ppl   error         lm_errors
E02000001  0.05575558    0.2228769     0.1554760                
E02000002  0.11299289    0.3680860     0.4357544            
E02000003  0.11938429    0.4785204     0.3163543            
E02000004  0.10767160    0.1978992     0.3909933            
E02000005  0.11138804    0.3544542     0.3370886            
E02000007  0.09484474    0.3447380     0.3881657
```

Output looks something like this:
[image]
Thanks!

Comment: Can you please `dput()` you data? The question is reproducible.

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean `dput()`?

Comment: Go ahead and try this code in your script ‘dput(data)’ and see what happens in the console. It produces a snapshot of your data that we can use to solve your problem

Comment: It produces a very long string of values from my dataset, probably too long to paste it here.

Comment: Then try dput(head(data)) and paste that in your post!

Comment: @mankojag what Serkan is pointing out is that the example in your question was not reproducible. For future questions you might have a look on a [How to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) example. I.e, to produce a minimal data set, you can use `head()`, `subset()`. Then use `dput()` to give us something that can be put in R immediately. Alternatively, you can use base R datasets (to see complete list `library(help = "datasets")`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to change a little your data so you can use `aes()` to set the color and the alpha. This is a very usefull trick with ggplot (you can find ways to do it, including the one presented here, on SO posts like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10349206/add-legend-to-ggplot2-line-plot)). You can find more general informations about pivoting here in the book [R for data science, chapter 12 Tidy data](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/tidy-data.html#tidy-data).

Accordingly, I pivot your dataframe to make a new variable called `error_type`. This new variable is then used inside `aes()` so the legend is created accordingly. Note that, using, `dplyr` pipe symbol `%>%` I pivot your dataframe just before entering ggplot world, without changing the original `df_index` object.

Then you can use`scale_alpha_manual()` and `scale_colour_manual()` to custom the color and the alpha the way you want it to be.

Here is a start:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

df_index %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = c("error", "lm_errors"), names_to = "error_type", values_to = "error_value") %>% 
  ggplot(data = ., aes(x = cases100ppl, 
                       y = error_value, 
                       color = error_type, 
                       alpha = error_type)) + # do not forget to put alpha inside aes()!
  scale_alpha_manual(values = c("error" = 0.3, "lm_errors" = 1)) +
  geom_point()
```

[image: ex_plot]

*Data:*

```
df_index <- structure(list(code = c("E02000001", "E02000002", "E02000003", 
                                    "E02000004", "E02000005", "E02000007"), cases100ppl = c(0.05575558, 
                                                                                            0.11299289, 0.11938429, 0.1076716, 0.11138804, 0.09484474), error = c(0.2228769, 
                                                                                                                                                                  0.368086, 0.4785204, 0.1978992, 0.3544542, 0.344738), lm_errors = c(0.155476, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      0.4357544, 0.3163543, 0.3909933, 0.3370886, 0.3881657)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   -6L))
```

Comment: Ok, that's looking good! How can I make it so that one error_type has a an alpha of some value, and the other has a different value?

Comment: @mankojag You can use `scale_alpha_manual()` and parameter the `value` argument with a named vector i.e. `scale_alpha_manual(values = c("error" = 0.6, "lm_error" = 1)`

Comment: `scale_alpha_manual(values = c(0.3, 1), breaks = c("error", "lm_errors"))` works also.

Comment: THis doesn't seem to be working: ```df_index %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = c("lm_errors", "error"), names_to = "error_type", values_to = "error_value") %>%
  arrange(desc(error_type)) %>%
  ggplot(data = ., aes(x = cases100ppl, 
                       y = error_value, 
                       color = error_type)) +
  scale_alpha_manual(values = c("error" = 0.2, "lm_error" = 1)) +
  geom_point()```

Comment: @mankojag please see the updated answer, I do not get an error. Also, you NEED to put `alpha` **inside** `aes()`

Comment: Okay, I get it now, thanks for your help!