# Add legend to multiline chart in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I have plotted 4 line on a chart:

```
ggplot() +
  geom_line(benchmark, mapping=aes(Date, EM))+
  geom_line(portfolio, mapping=aes(Date, EM), color="red") +
  geom_line(benchmark, mapping=aes(Date, CB))+
  geom_line(portfolio, mapping=aes(Date, CB), color="red")
```

How can I add a legend to this?

Comment: Please make a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add legend to ggplot2 line plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10349206/add-legend-to-ggplot2-line-plot)

Comment: The standard way to do this would be to melt/`pivot_longer` your data so that you had only a single `geom_line()`