# Adding legend to ggplot for forecasts

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization, legend

I have a ggplot for the different forecasts I used. Can you please help me add labels for the different forecasts? I pasted a copy of the code and a picture of the current graph. Don't mind the title, caption, and subtitle.

```
ggplot(Forecast_df, aes(date)) + 
  geom_tile(aes(alpha = Recession, y = 1), 
            fill = "grey", height = Inf) +
  scale_alpha_continuous(range = c(0, 1), breaks = c(0, 1), labels = c("0" = "Expansion", "1" = "Recession"))+
  geom_line(aes(y = ERVOLY), col = "black", size = .8)+
  geom_line(aes(y = ERVOL_vanilla), col = "blue", size = .8)+
  geom_line(aes(y = ERVOL_twofactor), col = "green", size = .8)+
  geom_line(aes(y = ERVOL_threefactor), col = "orange", size = .8)+
  ylab('Compounded Returns Next 12 Months (%)')+
  labs(x = NULL, alpha = "Economic Cylcle", color = "Economic Variable",
   title = "Rising Inflation Expectations in 2021",
   caption = 'Cleveland Fed Model of 10-year Inflation Expectations',
   subtitle = '"Directionality Matters"')+
  theme(plot.background = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.major= element_blank(),
    text = element_text( color = "#003366"))
```

[image: ggplot]

Here is a subset of the data (I hope this helps):

```
dput(head(Forecast_df, 10))


structure(list(INFEX = c(5.3755618, 5.2721824, 5.5661154, 5.407864, 
5.4896902, 5.1106146, 4.5055244, 4.6342849, 4.5102793, 4.6395631
), ERVOLY = c(NA, -1.0061220776063, -3.28324764731475, 
-2.69553459574718, 
-0.282378595190325, 0.452399878131127, -1.98818474608972, 
-2.02453229878801, 
-2.93519956175393, -3.3615903958241), date = structure(c(6695, 
6726, 6756, 6787, 6818, 6848, 6879, 6909, 6940, 6971), class = 
"Date"), 
Expansion = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), Recession = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), ERVOLY_lag1 = c(NA, NA, -1.0061220776063, 
-3.28324764731475, -2.69553459574718, -0.282378595190325, 
0.452399878131127, -1.98818474608972, -2.02453229878801, 
-2.93519956175393), ERVOLY_lag2 = c(NA, NA, NA, -1.0061220776063, 
-3.28324764731475, -2.69553459574718, -0.282378595190325, 
0.452399878131127, -1.98818474608972, -2.02453229878801), 
ERVOL_vanilla = c(NA, NA, NA, 0.177969523019507, 1.0226601086044, 
2.95027193254105, 2.8634033844251, 0.549544852368316, 
0.594205304832909, 
-0.162404463789272), ERVOL_twofactor = c(NA, NA, NA, 
0.0942849089685699, 
0.91074093410051, 2.85616681306392, 2.81947921688057, 
0.512592472075962, 
0.537863435836189, -0.222954102109839), ERVOL_threefactor = c(NA, 
NA, NA, -0.313401798360953, 0.474416484910883, 2.44479892124736, 
2.49154716920072, 0.199652448822007, 0.23023289110162, 
-0.537285874249354
), ERVOL_AR2 = c(NA, NA, NA, -3.24926540322977, -2.50081867707103, 
-0.136146400989865, 0.424591722149989, -2.06171545794125, 
-1.92397323156163, -2.82956410641666), fe_vanilla = c(NA, 
NA, NA, -2.87350411876669, -1.30503870379473, -2.49787205440993, 
-4.85158813051482, -2.57407715115632, -3.52940486658684, 
-3.19918593203483), fe_twofactor = c(NA, NA, NA, -2.78981950471575, 
-1.19311952929083, -2.4037669349328, -4.80766396297029, 
-2.53712477086397, 
-3.47306299759012, -3.13863629371426), fe_threefactor = c(NA, 
NA, NA, -2.38213279738623, -0.756795080101207, -1.99239904311623, 
-4.47973191529044, -2.22418474761001, -3.16543245285555, 
-2.82430452157474), fe_AR2 = c(NA, NA, NA, 0.553730807482581, 
2.21844008188071, 0.588546279120992, -2.41277646823971, 
0.0371831591532463, 
-1.0112263301923, -0.532026289407435)), row.names = c(NA, 
10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Does this answer your question: [Add legend to ggplot2 line plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10349206/add-legend-to-ggplot2-line-plot)

Comment: I would think so, but there is a piece of the puzzle I am missing if I counted these forecasts under the "Economic Variable" part of my code. Simply adding the scale_color_manual function with each color does not do the trick.

Comment: To help us to help you would you mind to provide [a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) including a snippet of your data. To share your data, you could type `dput(NAME_OF_DATASET)` into the console and copy & paste the output starting with `structure(....` into your post.  If your dataset has a lot of observations you could do e.g. `dput(head(NAME_OF_DATASET, 20))` for the first twenty rows of data.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the result you're looking for using the first method I'll outline here, although arguably a better way would be to first use `gather()` or `pivot_longer()` or `melt()` or `reshape()` to have a structure more resembling [Tidy Data](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tidyr/vignettes/tidy-data.html).  However, in the interest of space and time, I'll show the direct way here.

The reason why adding `scale_color_manual()` to your plot doesn't help is because the `scale_*` functions only *recolor/reshape an existing scale*.  Your original plot does not have a scale for color created, so you would be trying to recolor a scale that does not exist.  :)

The only scale your plot created was one for `alpha=`, and the reason is *because you specified that within `aes()`*.  This is the "secret" to creating a scale with `ggplot2`, because the plotting is setup to map an aesthetic attribute to a column in your dataframe.  There are positional aesthetics (like `x`, `y`, `width`, etc..) and then there are graphical aesthetics (like `color`, `fill`, `alpha`, `size`, etc...).  Positional aesthetics map your data to a location in the plot area, while the graphical aesthetics change the way a geom looks depending on your data.  For graphical aesthetics, **a legend is also created**.  So, to make a legend appear, you need your graphical aesthetics specified within `aes()`.

Specifying a value in `aes()` will set the name of the aesthetic in the legend.  Colors are then applied using the default scale... or via another scale you set using a `scale_*` command.  Here's an example without `scale_color_manual()`:

*(Note: had to remove `scale_alpha_continous()`, since your `dput()` only has one value for the "Recession" column).*

```
p <- ggplot(Forecast_df, aes(date)) + 
  geom_tile(aes(alpha = Recession, y = 1), 
            fill = "grey", height = Inf) +
  # scale_alpha_continuous(range = c(0, 1), breaks = c(0, 1), labels = c("Expansion", "Recession"))+
  geom_line(aes(y = ERVOLY, col="ERVOLY"), size = .8)+
  geom_line(aes(y = ERVOL_vanilla, col="Vanilla ERVOL"), size = .8)+
  geom_line(aes(y = ERVOL_twofactor, col="Twofactor ERVOL"), size = .8)+
  geom_line(aes(y = ERVOL_threefactor, col="Threefactor ERVOL"), size = .8)+
  ylab('Compounded Returns Next 12 Months (%)')+
  labs(x = NULL, alpha = "Economic Cylcle", color = "Economic Variable",
       title = "Rising Inflation Expectations in 2021",
       caption = 'Cleveland Fed Model of 10-year Inflation Expectations',
       subtitle = '"Directionality Matters"')+
  theme(plot.background = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.major= element_blank(),
        text = element_text( color = "#003366"))
p
```

[image]

You see, a legend is created and the keys are labeled accordingly.  You can then add the colors you want with `scale_color_manual()`:

```
p + scale_color_manual(values=c(
    "ERVOLY" = "black",
    "Vanilla ERVOL" = "blue",
    "Twofactor ERVOL"="green",
    "Threefactor ERVOL"="orange"))
```

[image]