# Is it Possible creating a Legend for non grouped data?

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend-properties

I want to obtain a plot that has a legend. In this legend, it shows the names `n`, and `m` which are in the `dfR`and their associated color. However, I have noticed this works only with groups, which is the case for the `iris` data set. I could be wrong, which is why I am here.

Any help would be appreciated!

```
# package:
library(tidyverse)

#df:
dfR<-data.frame(h=rnorm(n=5,mean=4,sd=3),
            m=rnorm(n=5,mean=19,sd=10),
            Z=rnorm(n=5,mean=9,sd=6))




  #Plot:
    p<-ggplot(data=dfR, aes(x=h))+
  labs(title="Title",
       subtitle="Subtitle",
       caption="Run number")+
         geom_line(aes(y=m),color="red")+
         geom_line(aes(y=Z),color="purple")
```

Comment: Does this answer your question: [Add legend to ggplot2 line plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10349206/add-legend-to-ggplot2-line-plot)

Comment: (p<-ggplot(data=dfR, aes(x=h))+
  labs(title="Title",
       subtitle="Subtitle",
       caption="Run number")+
  geom_line(aes(y=m,color="m"))+
  geom_line(aes(y=Z,color="z"))+
  scale_colour_manual(values=c("red","purple")))