# How to take the average of the values and make a dotted line graph, and change the polyline to a smooth curve? And add the legend?

Tags: r, ggplot2, mean, curve-fitting, dotted-line

I tried to take the average of **SF_Plante_Verte** and **SF_Plante_Totale** acccording to their **Date_obs**.

```
df<-structure(list(Pos_heliaphen = c("X47", "W17", "Z17", "X47", 
                                     "Y19", "Y40", "X47", "Y19", "Y40", "Z17", "Z31", "X47", "Y19", 
                                     "Y40", "Z31", "X47", "Z17", "Z31"), traitement = c("WW", "WW", 
                                                                                        "WW", "WW", "WW", "WW", "WW", "WW", "WW", "WW", "WW", "WW", "WW", 
                                                                                        "WW", "WW", "WW", "WW", "WW"), Variete = c("Blancas", "Blancas", 
                                                                                                                                   "Blancas", "Blancas", "Blancas", "Blancas", "Blancas", "Blancas", 
                                                                                                                                   "Blancas", "Blancas", "Blancas", "Blancas", "Blancas", "Blancas", 
                                                                                                                                   "Blancas", "Blancas", "Blancas", "Blancas"), Date_obs = c("D11_04/06/2021", 
                                                                                                                                                                                             "D11_04/06/2021", "D11_04/06/2021", "D12_07/06/2021", "D12_07/06/2021", 
                                                                                                                                                                                             "D12_07/06/2021", "D23_25/06/2021", "D23_25/06/2021", "D23_25/06/2021", 
                                                                                                                                                                                             "D23_25/06/2021", "D23_25/06/2021", "D24_28/06/2021", "D24_28/06/2021", 
                                                                                                                                                                                             "D24_28/06/2021", "D24_28/06/2021", "D25_29/06/2021", "D25_29/06/2021", 
                                                                                                                                                                                             "D25_29/06/2021"), SF_Plante_Totale = c(46473, 44589.3, 43134, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     166645.5, 119962.5, 93061.5, 483583.8, 313985.7, 273432.6, 414871.8, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     426766.2, 539410.2, 337417.5, 273432.6, 474915, 539410.2, 414871.8, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     474915), SF_Plante_Verte = c(46473, 44589.3, 43134, 162512.7, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  119962.5, 93061.5, 462655.2, 293367.9, 238373.1, 363123.6, 407572.2, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  473793.6, 316799.7, 238373.1, 420682.5, 473793.6, 363123.6, 420682.5
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     ), SF_Plante_senescence = c(0, 0, 0, 4132.8, 0, 0, 20928.6, 20617.8, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 35059.5, 51748.2, 19194, 65616.6, 20617.8, 35059.5, 54232.5, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 65616.6, 51748.2, 54232.5)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 ), row.names = c(NA, -18L))
```

With the code below, I want to draw a dotted line, but I want to get smooth curves instead of polylines (no polyline segments).And I can't add legend successfully either.

Could anyone please help save my problem? Thank you in advance!

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = Date_obs)) + 
  stat_summary(aes(y = SF_Plante_Totale,group=1), fun =mean, colour="white",shape=21,size=4,fill="steelblue",geom="point",group=1)+
  stat_summary(aes(y = SF_Plante_Totale,group=1), fun =mean,colour="steelblue", geom="smooth", group=1)+
  stat_summary(aes(y = SF_Plante_Verte,group=1), fun =mean, colour="white",shape=21,size=4,fill="tomato",geom="point",group=2)+
  stat_summary(aes(y = SF_Plante_Verte,group=1), fun =mean,colour="tomato", geom="smooth", group=1)+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1))
```

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add legend to ggplot2 line plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10349206/add-legend-to-ggplot2-line-plot)

Comment: The link refer to `geom_line`. I guess my graph also has `geom_point`, so it didn't work.@Dan Adams

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few issues here.

1. You don't get a legend because you specify the color manually to each layer outside of `aes()`. {ggplot2} won't automatically make a legend for things specified outside of `aes()`.
2. You can't access the different groups as a single variable to provide in `aes()` because your data is currently in 'wide' format where you have multiple columns containing the same type of data and the column names are simple metadata distinguishing those measurements. The solution is to convert to 'long' format. For this, I use `tidyr::pivot_longer()`.
3. To get your desired colors you can just use `scale_color_manual()`.
4. If you want to fit a smoothed curve rather than just a point-to-point line, you can use `loess` smoothing and simply adjust the `span` parameter to control how smooth or bumpy it is.
5. You can just change the `linetype` to get a dotted/dashed line. See [here](http://sape.inf.usi.ch/quick-reference/ggplot2/linetype) for more info on available options to control `linetype`.
6. If you want to separately visualize data from different `Pos_heliaphen` groups, it will help to add another aesthetic to distinguish them. For example you could use `shape` to distinguish the points and `linetype` to distinguish the smoothed lines.
7. I used `interaction()` to create all the combinations of the grouping variables.

```r
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  select(1, 4:6) %>% 
  pivot_longer(starts_with("SF")) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(Date_obs, value, color = name, group = interaction(name, Pos_heliaphen))) +
  geom_point(stat = "summary", size = 4, aes(shape = Pos_heliaphen)) +
  geom_smooth(method = "loess", se = F, span = 5, aes(linetype = Pos_heliaphen)) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("steelblue", "tomato")) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-04-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Hello Thank you so much for your answer! It did give me inspirations! I uploaded the more complete data. As you can see, the are more columns than before, I tried to use `pivot_longer(-Date_obs, names_to = c("SF_Plante_Verte", "SF_Plante_Totale"))` to select these two columns, but it didn't work.

Comment: And There are different **Pos_heliaphen** for a same **Date_obs**. I want to calculate the mean value for each **Date_obs** for the dotted curve (instead of polyline segments). Sorry to bother you again! @Dan Adams

Comment: `SF_Plante_Totale` and `SF_Plante_Verte` are currently `datetime` format. Is that your intention? When you plot it it is being treated as a plain `numeric` anyhow so you should be explicit if you're actually measuring time in those variables or if some other units.

Comment: No, I didn't intend to have datetime format. I have uploaded the newest data. But I still don't figure out how to achieve what I want.@Dan Adams

Comment: It will help if you can give a better idea of your expected output. Either an example graph from somewhere else, hand draw even, or just more explicit written description of how it should look with notes on which aesthetic parameters are mapped to which data features.

Comment: It works very well! Thank you so so so much!@Dan Adams