# Add legend to ggplot2 bar plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

**note that this question differs from [Add legend to ggplot2 line plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10349206/add-legend-to-ggplot2-line-plot)**. This is a multiple **bar** plot and the answers provided for **line** plots dont apply.

How can I add a legend to the below?

```
library(tidyr);library(ggplot2)   
date <- 2001:2050
dat1 <- 1:50
dat2 <- 50:1
data <- tibble(date, dat1, dat2)
p2 <- ggplot(data, aes(x=date)) +
  geom_bar(aes(y=dat1, color = "orange"), stat = "identity", fill="orange")+
  geom_bar(aes(y=dat2,color = "blue"), stat = "identity", fill="blue")+
  ggtitle("dat") + 
  ylab("unit") 
p2
```

As you can see the default legends and bars are wrongly filled.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add legend to ggplot2 line plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10349206/add-legend-to-ggplot2-line-plot)

Comment: as mentioned, it doesnt. The legends are wrong if I try to follow these answers, reason why i post a new question specifically for *bar* charts

Comment: it does not matter whether you have a bar or line chart; the same aesthetics apply, ggplot is build around this exact principle - also please don't post your question a second time if the first was flagged as an duplicate

Comment: Please do not include commentary about the workings of the site in the question body itself. If you disagree with the actions taken, instead, post a question on [Meta StackOverflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```r
library(tidyverse)

date <- 2001:2050
dat1 <- 1:50
dat2 <- 50:1
data <- tibble(date, dat1, dat2)

data %>%
  pivot_longer(c(dat1, dat2)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(date, value, fill = name)) +
  geom_col(position = position_identity())+
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("orange", "blue")) +
  ggtitle("dat") + 
  ylab("unit") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, vjust = 0.5, hjust=1))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-06-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>