# Issues with making legend for scatterplot in rstudio

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to create a legend for my scatterplot however, the colors do not match. Rather the output is displayed like the image below.
[plot output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xw0qw.png)

Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Here is my code:

```
ggplot() +
  geom_point(data = dfreq, aes(x = as.numeric(month), y = dnorm, color = "Dallas"), shape = 21, fill = "#899AD6", size = 3) + 
  geom_line(data = dfreq, aes(x = as.numeric(month), y = dnorm, color = "Dallas")) +
  geom_point(data = lfreq, aes(x = as.numeric(month), y = lnorm, color = "Los Angeles"), shape = 21, fill = "#E47080", size = 3) +
  geom_line(data = lfreq, aes(x = as.numeric(month), y = lnorm, color = "Los Angeles")) +
  ggtitle("Crime by Month in Dallas vs. Los Angeles") +
  xlab("Month") + ylab("Frequency of Crime") +
  scale_color_manual(name = "City", values = c("Dallas" = "#899AD6", "Los Angeles" = "#E47080")) +
  theme(axis.text = element_text(size = 7)) +
  scale_x_continuous(name = "Month", breaks = 1:12, labels = month.name[1:12])
```

Comment: your plotting approach is ineffective. Your data seems to have the same column names. Merge your data and plot those lines / dots following the suggestions for example in this thread.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3777174/plotting-two-variables-as-lines-using-ggplot2-on-the-same-graph (and in this case only do not follow Hadley's advice)

Comment: Also useful, arguably the same, but maybe from a different perspective: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10349206/add-legend-to-ggplot2-line-plot

Comment: Drop `shape = 21, fill = "#899AD6"` from your code and you should be fine. Nonetheless the proper `ggplot2` way would be to bind your datasets into one using e.g. `dat <- list("Dallas" = dfreq, "Los Angeles" = lfreq) |> lapply(dplyr::rename, norm = 2) |> dplyr::bind_rows(.id = "city")`. Doing so you could simplify your plotting code as you now have a city column which could be mapped on `color` and you can create your plot with just one geom_line and geom_point.