# ggplot2 and cumsum()

Tags: r, ggplot2, cumsum

I have a set of UNIX timestamps and URIs and I'm trying to plot the cumulative count of requests for each URI. I managed to do that for one URI at a time using a dummy column:

```
x.df$count <- apply(x.df,1,function(row) 1) # Create a dummy column for cumsum
x.df <- x.df[order(x.df$time, decreasing=FALSE),] # Sort
ggplot(x.df, aes(x=time, y=cumsum(count))) + geom_line()
```

However, that would make roughly 30 plots in my case.

ggplot2 does allow you to plot multiple lines into one plot (I copied this piece of code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3777174/plotting-two-variables-as-lines-using-ggplot2)):

```
ggplot(data=test_data_long, aes(x=date, y=value, colour=variable)) +
    geom_line()
```

The problem is that, this way, `cumsum()` would count on and on.

Does anybody have an idea?

Comment: Can you provide a small example data set that illustrates what you're describing?

Comment: this sounds like a job for `plyr` or `data.table`.  Split the data by URI then to your `cumsum` on each piece. `data.table(x); x[, list(count=.I), by=URI]`  Or something like that...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's a test data which uses `plyr`'s `transform` to calculate the cumulative sum first and then apply that data to plot using `ggplot2`:

```
set.seed(45)
DF <- data.frame(grp = factor(rep(1:5, each=10)), x=rep(1:10, 5))
DF <- transform(DF, y=runif(nrow(DF)))

# use plyr to calculate cumsum per group of x
require(plyr)
DF.t <- ddply(DF, .(grp), transform, cy = cumsum(y))

# plot
require(ggplot2)
ggplot(DF.t, aes(x=x, y=cy, colour=grp, group=grp)) + geom_line()
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand what you meant by sample data, I'm still rather new with R. Your plot doesn't actually show the cumulative sums, though. The lines would have to be monotonic. (BTW: You wouldn't need cumsum to create that kind of lines, ECDF would do the job.)

Comment: I generated some sample data, as you dint provide one (see @joran's comment). I guess you are still looking at the old plot? This *is* monotonic and is the cumulative sum. if you want to see the points just add, `+ geom_point()`.

Comment: Hi Arun, thanks for your help. The example worked, but I simply didn't get a monotonic plot for the actual data. So I started to play around with the numbers in the example and I think there's a problem with big numbers. Can you reproduce this?

Comment: @Bob the onus is on you to provide a reproducible example.

Comment: I think I have identified the problem with my data. Looks like you will not get a monotonic plot if your data is not sorted in increasing order.