# Incorrectly displayed linetypes in the legend with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm following this links [example](https://www.r-bloggers.com/ggplot2-multiple-legends-for-the-same-aesthetic/), as I have a similar situation where I'm trying to graph two data frames in the same plot. I'm only interested in changing the linetypes for one of the data frames, which works in the graph, but doesn't display correctly in the legend.

Example dataset:

```
set.seed(456)
n <- 20
dfr <- data.frame(
  id=rep(1:n, 2),
  group=rep(c("1","2"), each=n), value=c(rnorm(n), rnorm(n, sd=1.1))
)

df_95ci <- data.frame(y_values=c(-1,1)*qnorm(0.95)) 
df_99ci <- data.frame(y_values=c(-1,1)*qnorm(0.99))

require(ggplot2)
```

Code:

```
  ggplot(data=dfr, mapping=aes(x=id, y=value)) +
  geom_line(mapping=aes(colour=group)) +
  geom_hline(data= df_95ci, mapping=aes(yintercept=y_values, size= "95% CI"), colour = "orange", linetype="dotdash") +
  geom_hline(data= df_99ci, mapping=aes(yintercept=y_values, size= "99% CI"), colour = "darkred", linetype="dotted") +
  scale_color_hue("Group") +
  scale_size_manual(
    "CI horizontal line", values=rep(1,4),
    guide=guide_legend(override.aes = list(colour=c("orange", "darkred")))
  ) +
  scale_linetype_identity(guide="legend")
```

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sT18h.png)

As you can see I have two lines with different linetypes, but they're identical in the legend.

Comment: The simple solution is to label them the same way you did `size =` inside the aesthetics, and add a `scale_linetype_manual` the same way you did for size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you want this?

```
ggplot(data=dfr, mapping=aes(x=id, y=value)) +
    geom_line(mapping=aes(colour=group)) +
    geom_hline(data= df_95ci, mapping=aes(yintercept=y_values, linetype= "95% CI"), 
               colour = "orange", size = 1) +
    geom_hline(data= df_99ci, mapping=aes(yintercept=y_values, linetype= "99% CI"), 
               colour = "darkred", size = 1) +
    scale_linetype_manual(
        "CI horizontal line", values=c("95% CI" = 4, "99% CI" = 3),
        guide=guide_legend(override.aes = list(colour=c("orange", "darkred")))
    )
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks that worked. My own graph/code which is a little more complex had some difficulty with the linetypes not showing up in "WHO 2007 growth references" (http://i.imgur.com/RYR3Xex.png), but I managed to get it working after taking some inspiration from here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20378276/legend-does-not-show-line-type-in-ggplot2-density-plot).

For others: the alpha value is a nuisance when adjusting the legend if you have an alpha argument in the geoms. It's better to disable it first to see if that's causing the vanishing linetypes/other legend indicators.

Comment: @VYu Good for you!