# R: linetype and color manual not showing in ggplot legend

Tags: ggplot2, legend, roc, auc

I'm plotting the following data (stored as `data.frame` object) as ROC-AUC plot using `ggplot`. I want to display each data in unique linetype and color and arrange them into a legend inside the plot, so I referenced this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20378276/legend-does-not-show-line-type-in-ggplot2-density-plot), but my code (at below) doesn't seem to work. Linetype and color are just not showing on the legend. If will be really appreciated if someone could point out the error in my code or suggest alternative way to achieve the desired result.

```css
library(ggplot2)

df1 <- readRDS(url("https://www.dropbox.com/s/rtkyjs4af9h0qhx/df1.rds?dl=1"))
df2 <- readRDS(url("https://www.dropbox.com/s/r3qlvm36ybxqpcz/df2.rds?dl=1"))
df3 <- readRDS(url("https://www.dropbox.com/s/ebd8vu3l8iefzcz/df3.rds?dl=1"))
df4 <- readRDS(url("https://www.dropbox.com/s/cud2g0xijcc5cql/df4.rds?dl=1"))
df5 <- readRDS(url("https://www.dropbox.com/s/pzaznhozuxywnuc/df5.rds?dl=1"))
df6 <- readRDS(url("https://www.dropbox.com/s/n8ryyboznmxf1dq/df6.rds?dl=1"))


ggplot() + 
  geom_line(data = df1, aes(X3, X2, col = "Model 1: 76.9", linetype = "Model 1: 76.9"), size = 1.1, alpha=0.8) + 
  geom_line(data = df2, aes(X3, X2, col = "Model 2: 78.3", linetype = "Model 2: 78.3"), size = 1.1, alpha=0.8) + 
  geom_line(data = df3, aes(X3, X2, col = "Model 3: 77.2", linetype = "Model 3: 77.2"), size = 1.1, alpha=0.6) + 
  geom_line(data = df4, aes(X3, X2, col = "Model 4: 77.3", linetype = "Model 4: 77.3"), size = 1.1, alpha=0.6) + 
  geom_line(data = df5, aes(X3, X2, col = "Model 5: 78.5", linetype = "Model 5: 78.5"), size = 1.1, alpha=0.4) + 
  geom_line(data = df6, aes(X3, X2, col = "Model 6: 78.5", linetype = "Model 6: 78.5"), size = 1.1, alpha=0.4) + 
  scale_color_manual(name = "       Model  AUC", 
                     values = c("Model 1: 76.9" = "#F8766D", "Model 2: 78.3" = "#F8766D", "Model 3: 77.2" = "#00BFC4", "Model 4: 77.3" = "#00BFC4", "Model 5: 78.5" = "#00BFC4", "Model 6: 78.5" = "#00BFC4")) +
  scale_linetype_manual(name = "       Model  AUC", values = c("Model 1: 76.9" = "solid", "Model 2: 78.3" = "dotted", "Model 3: 77.2" = "solid", "Model 4: 77.3" = "dotted", "Model 5: 78.5" = "dashed", "Model 6: 78.5" = "dotdash")) +
  labs(title="ROC AUC", x ="1 - Specificity (%)", y = "Sensitivity (%)") +
  theme_bw() + scale_x_continuous(labels = c(0, 25, 50, 75, 100)) +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5), legend.position = c(0.80, 0.35))
```

[image: pic]

Comment: Have you tried using ggsave?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is only happening in your plot panel, try  `ggsave` for example.

In my plot panel, it looked the same as in your picture:

[image]

However, after saving it in a folder, I get colors and linetypes:

[image]