# plotting temperature Vs time in R

Tags: r, time, plot, temperature

I would like to plot the semi-hourly temperatures of 3 places into one plot. This is how the files look like (this is a part of `Noble2.csv`; the other files are `Noble3.csv` and `Noble6.csv`):

```
    Time    Temp
1   08/20/14 02:05:02 PM    17.034
2   08/20/14 02:35:02 PM    16.749
3   08/20/14 03:05:02 PM    16.963
4   08/20/14 03:35:02 PM    16.820
5   08/20/14 04:05:02 PM    16.963
6   08/20/14 04:35:02 PM    17.153
7   08/20/14 05:05:02 PM    16.249
8   08/20/14 05:35:02 PM    15.652
9   08/20/14 06:05:02 PM    14.649
10  08/20/14 06:35:02 PM    13.906
11  08/20/14 07:05:02 PM    13.209
12  08/20/14 07:35:02 PM    12.316
13  08/20/14 08:05:02 PM    12.268
14  08/20/14 08:35:02 PM    12.243
15  08/20/14 09:05:02 PM    12.219
16  08/20/14 09:35:02 PM    12.171
17  08/20/14 10:05:02 PM    12.147
18  08/20/14 10:35:02 PM    12.122
19  08/20/14 11:05:02 PM    12.074
```

Noble3.csv:

```
Time    Temp
```

1   08/20/14 02:06:59 PM    15.438
2   08/20/14 02:36:59 PM    13.882
3   08/20/14 03:06:59 PM    13.642
4   08/20/14 03:36:59 PM    13.353
5   08/20/14 04:06:59 PM    13.666
6   08/20/14 04:36:59 PM    12.074
7   08/20/14 05:06:59 PM    12.147
8   08/20/14 05:36:59 PM    12.219
9   08/20/14 06:06:59 PM    12.268
10  08/20/14 06:36:59 PM    12.292
11  08/20/14 07:06:59 PM    12.292
12  08/20/14 07:36:59 PM    12.268
13  08/20/14 08:06:59 PM    12.268
14  08/20/14 08:36:59 PM    12.243
15  08/20/14 09:06:59 PM    12.219
16  08/20/14 09:36:59 PM    12.171
17  08/20/14 10:06:59 PM    12.147
18  08/20/14 10:36:59 PM    12.122
19  08/20/14 11:06:59 PM    12.098

And Noble6.csv:

```
Time    Temp
```

1   08/19/14 04:59:27 PM    12.001
2   08/19/14 05:29:27 PM    12.050
3   08/19/14 05:59:27 PM    12.122
4   08/19/14 06:29:27 PM    12.147
5   08/19/14 06:59:27 PM    12.171
6   08/19/14 07:29:27 PM    12.195
7   08/19/14 07:59:27 PM    12.219
8   08/19/14 08:29:27 PM    12.195
9   08/19/14 08:59:27 PM    12.171
10  08/19/14 09:29:27 PM    12.122
11  08/19/14 09:59:27 PM    12.074
12  08/19/14 10:29:27 PM    12.025
13  08/19/14 10:59:27 PM    11.977
14  08/19/14 11:29:27 PM    11.929
15  08/19/14 11:59:27 PM    11.880
16  08/20/14 12:29:27 AM    11.832
17  08/20/14 12:59:27 AM    11.783
18  08/20/14 01:29:27 AM    11.734
19  08/20/14 01:59:27 AM    11.662
20  08/20/14 02:29:27 AM    11.613

First, I tried to put the time column with a time format with the following commands:

```
> NB2<-strptime(Noble2$Time, "%m/%d/%y %I:%M:%S %p")  
> NB3<-strptime(Noble3$Time, "%m/%d/%y %I:%M:%S %p")  
> NB6<-strptime(Noble6$Time, "%m/%d/%y %I:%M:%S %p")
```

then I tried to put the temperature values as a list to be able to use the function plot:

```
> NB2T<-Noble2$Temp  
> NB3T<-Noble3$Temp  
> NB6T<-Noble6$Temp
```

just to check how it looks (before trying to put the 3 lines within one graph) I tried to plot NB2 Vs NB2T:

```
plot(NB2,NB2T,type="l",col="red")
```

this is what I got: [this](https://www.dropbox.com/s/6ku1h47gz1x045w/Rplot.jpeg?dl=0) - which makes no sense. I should have gotten something like [this](https://www.dropbox.com/s/o2mlh4pmgoilrac/graph.jpg?dl=0) (this one was made in excel).

I haven't got to the phase of adding the three lines to one graph, but could you point me into the right direction to get a correct graph first and how to add the other two lines to the graph?

Comment: Can you show what the NB2 and NB2T vectors look like?

Comment: Hey, a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) would help a lot. Can you `dput()` part of your data? I tried the first 3 lines of your data and the plot looks fine for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
library(ggplot2)
library(scales) # to access breaks/formatting functions
ggplot(aes(x = Time, y = Temp), data = Noble2) + geom_line()
last_plot()+scale_x_datetime(breaks = date_breaks("30 mins"))
```

If you want the [dynamic](http://rstudio.github.io/dygraphs/) graph, you can proceed as follows:

```
library(dygraphs)
library(xts)
x1<-read.csv("Noble2.csv",na.strings = c("NA", ""))
x2<-x1[complete.cases(x1),]
x2$Time<-strptime(x2$Time, "%m/%d/%y %I:%M:%S %p") 
#convert to xts object before using dygraph
x3<- xts(x2[,-1], order.by=x2[,1]) 
dygraph(x3[1:7625,]) %>% # last two observations still give the NA's (not sure why)
dyRangeSelector(height = 20)
```

Comment: the dates on the x axis are wrong... went to the original file and noticed the dates are wrong on the original (some are in m/d/y and others are in d/m/y). I'll get back once I solve this one first. Thank you a lot

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Noble2$Time = as.POSIXct(Noble2$Time,format="%m/%d/%y %I:%M:%S %p")
plot(Temp~Time,data=Noble2,type='l',col='red')
```

You want to make sure you're casting your datetimes at POSIXct types, not POSIXlt types.

Answer (score 0):

Tried the first three rows of your data, plot looks fine.

Maybe the problem is with parsing the CSV files?

```
NB2 <- structure(list(sec = c(2, 2, 2), min = c(5L, 35L, 5L), hour = c(14L, 
 14L, 15L), mday = c(20L, 20L, 20L), mon = c(7L, 7L, 7L), year = c(114L, 
 114L, 114L), wday = c(3L, 3L, 3L), yday = c(231L, 231L, 231L), 
     isdst = c(1L, 1L, 1L), zone = c("EDT", "EDT", "EDT"), gmtoff = c(NA_integer_, 
     NA_integer_, NA_integer_)), .Names = c("sec", "min", "hour", 
 "mday", "mon", "year", "wday", "yday", "isdst", "zone", "gmtoff"
 ), class = c("POSIXlt", "POSIXt"))

NB2T <- c(17.034, 16.749, 16.963)

plot(NB2, NB2T, type="l")
```

[image]

To add the other series to your plot with base graphics, you can use `lines`, e.g.:

```
plot(NB2, NB2T, type="l")
lines(NB3, NB3T, color="red")
```

Or with `ggplot2`, e.g. [look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3777174/plotting-two-variables-as-lines-using-ggplot2-on-the-same-graph)