# Plotting the same from differently organised input files

Tags: r, ggplot2

I got the following CSV input file (column are separated by tab):

```
fruits     A      B     C
apple      9.8    21    62.2
bananas    12     11    58.3
pineapple  3.5    13    41.2
kiwi       6.4    36.5  38.1
strawberry 2.5    47.2  35.5
```

But did not managed to plot the graph using ggplot. Instead of this I created the same input but a bit different

```
fruits      Who How Much
apple       A   9.8
bananas     A   12
pineapple   A   3.5
kiwi        A   6.4
strawberry  A   2.5
apple       B   21
bananas     B   11
pineapple   B   13
kiwi        B   36.5
strawberry  B   47.2
apple       C   62.2
bananas     C   58.3
pineapple   C   41.2
kiwi        C   38.1
strawberry  C   35.5
```

Then i read the data

```
data <- read.table(file.choose(), header = TRUE, sep= '\t')
```

and plotted it with

```
ggplot(data=data, aes(x=Who, y=HowMuch, group=Fruits, colour=Fruits)) + 
       geom_line() + geom_point() + ggtitle("Fruits") + theme_bw() + 
       theme(legend.position=c(.9, .3)) + theme(legend.title=element_blank())
```

How can I do the same plot using my original input file from  the beginning of the post ? Without creating the new input file..

Comment: The general approach in ggplot2 is to work with data in a long format instead of a wide format.  You can do the reshaping after reading the data in rather than making a different input file via, e.g., `reshape2::melt`.  Lots of examples on SO, including [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3777592/2461552)

Answer (score 2):

obligatory tidyverse solution:

```
library(tidyr)

read.table(text="fruits     A      B     C
apple      9.8    21    62.2
bananas    12     11    58.3
pineapple  3.5    13    41.2
kiwi       6.4    36.5  38.1
strawberry 2.5    47.2  35.5", header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE) -> df

gather(df, who, how_much, -fruits)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
fruits<-c("apple","bananas","pineapple","kiwi","strawberry")
A<-c("9.8","12","3.5","6.4","2.5")
B<-c("21","11","13","36.5","47.2")
C<-c("62.2","58.3","41.2","38.1","35.5")

df<-data.frame(fruits, A, B, C)
df
      fruits   A    B    C
1      apple 9.8   21 62.2
2    bananas  12   11 58.3
3  pineapple 3.5   13 41.2
4       kiwi 6.4 36.5 38.1
5 strawberry 2.5 47.2 35.5

library(reshape2)
melt(df, id="fruits")

       fruits variable value
1       apple        A   9.8
2     bananas        A    12
3   pineapple        A   3.5
4        kiwi        A   6.4
5  strawberry        A   2.5
6       apple        B    21
7     bananas        B    11
8   pineapple        B    13
9        kiwi        B  36.5
10 strawberry        B  47.2
11      apple        C  62.2
12    bananas        C  58.3
13  pineapple        C  41.2
14       kiwi        C  38.1
15 strawberry        C  35.5
```