# Multiple lines on one ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, multiple-columns

My data is an imported excel file where the first column is the sample time and is the 'x-axis' and the remaining columns are the measurement. They are the same measurements but taken from different subjects.

A snapshot of how the data looks is below:

[image]

I can stack them up on ggplot manually using:

```
ggplot(P2ROKI, aes(x=P2ROKI$Time))+
  geom_point(aes(y=P2ROKI$P1, colour="P1"))+
  geom_point(aes(y=P2ROKI$P6, colour="P6")) + 
  geom_smooth(aes(y=P2ROKI$P1, colour="P1")) + 
  geom_smooth(aes(y=P2ROKI$P6, colour="P6"))
```

However I wondered if there was a simpler way where I could do it in one go?

Comment: Please don't share data as images. We can't use that.

Comment: Look at the answers by rcs and ecerulm on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3777174/plotting-two-variables-as-lines-using-ggplot2-on-the-same-graph). You should reshape your data. Also, never use `$` inside `aes`, just give the bare variable names instead.

Comment: Thanks - I have managed to make it work. Your advice was very helpful

Comment: Great, good to hear.