# Boxplox data frame

Tags: r, boxplot

I have a data frame like this:

```
2015 | 2016 | 2017 
-----+------+------
1.2  |  5.2 | 5.6
9.1  |  3.7 | 4.3
.../...
```

and I'd like to box plot the values of the column for each year.

The only way I found is to manually change the data frame (imported from CSV file) into:

```
Year | Value
-----+-------
2015 | 1.2
...  | ...
2016 | 5.2
...  | ...
2017 | 5.6
...  | ...
```

and use (if CPV is the name of my data frame):

```
ggplot(CPV, aes(x=factor(Year), y=Time)) + geom_boxplot()
```

First question: can I get the same result with the first form of data frame?

Second question: can I have the same plot if I have a "Value" column, and for each year, the count of occurences of this value:

```
Value | 2015 | 2016 | ...
------+------+------+---
1     |    0 |    5 | ...
1.1   |    4 |    1 | ...
```

**ANSWER**

1. Use the second form of the table for the box plot.
2. To get to this form, use the `melt` function from the `data.table` package.

Comment: Please include [reproducible data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: The answer to the first question is NO. The second form which you have shown is the `melt` form of data (and that is the right way to do). For the second question, once you have the occurrences, you can again melt the data and create boxplot. Do you need the `value` column as well?

Comment: Possible duplicate of the first part: [Plotting two variables as lines using ggplot2 on the same graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3777174/plotting-two-variables-as-lines-using-ggplot2-on-the-same-graph). The second question should be, well, a second question.

Comment: @Hardikgupta The `value` column represents the Y-Axis of the plot, but I don't need them otherwise.

Comment: @gregseth: you can then melt the dataframe (from library reshape) and use the occurrence data only to create boxplot

Comment: @Hardikgupta I think I got the melt part working, but not sure how to use the occurrence data only to create boxplot.

Comment: @lmo Since my questions are about how to use some R functions, any data will do. There's no «error» to reproduce.

Comment: @Henrik I'll reformulate my second question then: How, from the input data shown in the last table, can I get the same boxplot than with the code line I provided? Or, in other words should I transform the data frame #3 to make it look like #2, or is there some way to use it as is, with some ggplot parameters?

Answer (score 1):

```
df <- data.frame("2015" = c(1.2, 9.2),
             "2016" = c(5.2, 3.7),
             "2017" = c(5.6, 4.3))
names(df2) <- c("Year", "Value")             # new
# setnames(df, as.character(c(2015:2017)))   # old
```

reshape2 will do the transformation of the data frame:

```
library(reshape2)
df2 <- melt(df)
setnames(df2, c("Year", "Value"))
df2
```

Then you can generate the boxplot as you did before:

```
ggplot(df2, aes(x = factor(Year), y = Value)) + geom_boxplot()
```

Comment: `setnames` is not a base R function. Please list any packages you are using in your answer.