# multiple line charts of different columns in r using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am new in using ggplot2.
i have this data

```
 Boys    Girls
 1 61.36190 67.55333
 2 66.23038 70.15116
 3 68.29894 73.06008
 4 64.95406 70.54364
 5 65.34404 74.34307
```

and I want to show line chart of both columns boys and girls  in one single graph using ggplot2
is this possible using  ggplot2 ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3777174/plotting-two-variables-as-lines-using-ggplot2-on-the-same-graph

Comment: thank you so much .......can i do same thing with which other graphs ? i meant multiple charts of multiple columns  in same graph

Comment: Yes. Please google for a 'tutorial in ggplot2'. It might give you a good start in learning and applying ggplot2.