# Plot multiple lines each with unique color in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

So I am a bit of an R novice, I am trying to plot a graph that has multiple line each colour coded. My data is currently in the format of 3 columns (Name,Total, Year) and 270 rows. There is 15 years for each name and the data looks something similar to this:

```
Name  Year  Total
X      1      4
Y      1      6
Z      1      3
```

I want each name to have its own line running from the first year in the data to the last with the totals being plotted. I am however unaware how to separate out each of these names to ensure that they are plotted separately. My data is currently in a tab delimited text file from excel. I was wondering how to proceed from here. Any help is appreciated

Comment: if you use `dput(head(df))` to share the head of your data frame here and the plot you are using (the code for it) I can help you reshape the data to get what you want

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Plotting two variables as lines using ggplot2 on the same graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3777174/plotting-two-variables-as-lines-using-ggplot2-on-the-same-graph)

Comment: structure(c("function (x, df1, df2, ncp, log = FALSE) ", "{", 
"    if (missing(ncp)) ", "        .Call(C_df, x, df1, df2, log)", 
"    else .Call(C_dnf, x, df1, df2, ncp, log)", "}"), .Dim = c(6L, 
1L), .Dimnames = list(c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"), ""), class = "noquote")

Answer (score 1):

With `tidyverse` it should look like this:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
ggplot(aes(x = Year, y = Total, color = Name)) +
geom_line()
```