# Ploting in ggplot2 with geom_line() with label

Tags: r, ggplot2, label, geom-text

I'm trying to plot this dataset with ggplot2, putting the name of each country in each line geom_line() and with the x axis (Year) and the y axis (with the relevant data from each country).

[The DataSet to Edit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oHS4P.png)

[This is what I have so far. I wanted to include the name of the country in each line. The problem is that each country has its data in a separate column.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aJI9N.png)

Comment: This comment may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3777592/9229402
It shows how to `melt` your dataset and then create labels automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use `ggplot` you should bring your data into a "longer" format. Using package `tidyr`:

```r
df %<>%
  pivot_longer(cols=matches("[^Year]"),
               names_to="Country", 
               values_to="Value")
```

gives you

```r
# A tibble: 108 x 3
    Year Country       Value
   <dbl> <chr>         <dbl>
 1  1995 Argentina   4122262
 2  1995 Bolivia     3409890
 3  1995 Brazil     36276255
 4  1995 Chile       2222563
 5  1995 Colombia   10279222
 6  1995 Costa_Rica  1611055
 7  1997 Argentina   4100563
 8  1997 Bolivia     3391943
 9  1997 Brazil     35718095
10  1997 Chile       2208382
```

Based on this it is easy to plot a line for each country using `ggplot2`:

```r
ggplot(df, aes(x=Year, y=Value, color=Country)) + 
  geom_line()
```

Comment: Thank you Martin! That was very helpful!

Answer (score 1):

You kind of answered your question. You require the package reshape to bring all countries into a single column.

```
    Year<-c(1991,1992,1993,1994,1995,1996)
Argentina<-c(235,531,3251,3153,13851,16513)
Mexico<-c(16503,16035,3516,3155,30351,16513)
Japan<-c(1651,868416,68165,35135,03,136816)

df<-data.frame(Year,Argentina,Mexico,Japan)

library(reshape2)

df2<- melt(data = df, id.vars = "Year", Cont.Val=c("Argentina","Mexico","Japan"))

library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df2, aes(x=Year, y=value, group=variable, color=variable))+
  geom_line()
```