# ggplot2 add colors to legend

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am creating a multi-line chart with legend, but I'm not sure how to force the squares in the legend to be the same color as my lines.

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=Month)) +
  geom_line(aes(y=`Less than a high school diploma`/100, color="Less Than HS Diploma"), size=2, alpha=0.5, linetype=1) +
  geom_line(aes(y=`High school graduates, no college`/100, color="HS Diploma"), size=2, alpha=0.5, linetype=1) + 
  geom_line(aes(y=`Some college or associate degree`/100, color="Some College / Associate's Degree"), size=2, alpha=0.5, linetype=1) +
  geom_line(aes(y=`Bachelor's degree and higher`/100, color="Bachelor's Degree and Higher"), size=2, alpha=0.5, linetype=1) +
  scale_color_manual(name="Educational Attainment", values = c("Less Than HS Diploma"="deepskyblue", "HS Diploma" = "firebrick1", "Some College / Associate's Degree"="mediumpurple", "Bachelor's Degree and Higher"="springgreen4")) +
  ggtitle("Unemployment Rate by Educational Attainment") +
  xlab("Time") +
  ylab("Unemployment Rate") +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent) +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5), legend.position="bottom")
```

[image]

Comment: Seems relevant [Plotting two variables as lines using ggplot2 on the same graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3777174/plotting-two-variables-as-lines-using-ggplot2-on-the-same-graph)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main issue is the `alpha` argument together with `geom_line`. If you want the keys to show up as lines you set alpha to 1 in the legend via `guides(color = guide_legend(override.aes = list(alpha = c(1, 1, 1, 1))))`. If you want colored rectangles for the keys this could be achieved by adding `key_glyph = "rect"` to your `geom_line` layers

Using the `economics` dataset as example data:

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(economics, aes(x=date)) +
  geom_line(aes(y=`psavert`/100, color="Less Than HS Diploma"), size=2, alpha=0.5, linetype=1) +
  geom_line(aes(y=`uempmed`/100, color="HS Diploma"), size=2, alpha=0.5, linetype=1) + 
  geom_line(aes(y=`psavert`/10, color="Some College / Associate's Degree"), size=2, alpha=0.5, linetype=1) +
  geom_line(aes(y=`uempmed`/10, color="Bachelor's Degree and Higher"), size=2, alpha=0.5, linetype=1) +
  scale_color_manual(name="Educational Attainment", values = c("Less Than HS Diploma"="deepskyblue", "HS Diploma" = "firebrick1", "Some College / Associate's Degree"="mediumpurple", "Bachelor's Degree and Higher"="springgreen4")) +
  guides(color = guide_legend(override.aes = list(alpha = c(1, 1, 1, 1)))) +
  ggtitle("Unemployment Rate by Educational Attainment") +
  xlab("Time") +
  ylab("Unemployment Rate") +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent) +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5), legend.position="bottom")
```

[image]

And with `key_glyph="rect"`:

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(economics, aes(x=date)) +
  geom_line(aes(y=`psavert`/100, color="Less Than HS Diploma"), size=2,alpha=0.5,  linetype=1, key_glyph = "rect") +
  geom_line(aes(y=`uempmed`/100, color="HS Diploma"), size=2, alpha=0.5, linetype=1, key_glyph = "rect") + 
  geom_line(aes(y=`psavert`/10, color="Some College / Associate's Degree"), size=2, alpha=0.5, linetype=1, key_glyph = "rect") +
  geom_line(aes(y=`uempmed`/10, color="Bachelor's Degree and Higher"), size=2, alpha=0.5, linetype=1, key_glyph = "rect") +
  scale_color_manual(name="Educational Attainment", values = c("Less Than HS Diploma"="deepskyblue", "HS Diploma" = "firebrick1", "Some College / Associate's Degree"="mediumpurple", "Bachelor's Degree and Higher"="springgreen4")) +
  ggtitle("Unemployment Rate by Educational Attainment") +
  xlab("Time") +
  ylab("Unemployment Rate") +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent) +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5), legend.position="bottom")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-10-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

The `values` argument from `scale_color_manual` should have color names instead of the line names, which you don't need to pass. Example:

```
scale_color_manual(name="Educational Attainment", values = c("red","yellow","white",...))
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work (No output included as no data was shared). If you want the legend filled, you must also enable inside `aes()` the option `fill`. After that you can scale the colors for filling with `scale_fill_manual()` and use `labs()` to give them a common name. Here the code:

```
library(ggplot2)
#Code
ggplot(df, aes(x=Month)) +
  geom_line(aes(y=`Less than a high school diploma`/100,
                color="Less Than HS Diploma",
                fill="Less Than HS Diploma"), size=2, alpha=0.5, linetype=1) +
  geom_line(aes(y=`High school graduates, no college`/100,
                color="HS Diploma",
                fill="HS Diploma"), size=2, alpha=0.5, linetype=1) + 
  geom_line(aes(y=`Some college or associate degree`/100,
                color="Some College / Associate's Degree",
                fill="Some College / Associate's Degree"), size=2, alpha=0.5, linetype=1) +
  geom_line(aes(y=`Bachelor's degree and higher`/100,
                color="Bachelor's Degree and Higher",
                fill="Bachelor's Degree and Higher"), size=2, alpha=0.5, linetype=1) +
  scale_color_manual(name="Educational Attainment",
                     values = c("Less Than HS Diploma"="deepskyblue",
                                "HS Diploma" = "firebrick1",
                                "Some College / Associate's Degree"="mediumpurple",
                                "Bachelor's Degree and Higher"="springgreen4")) +
  scale_fill_manual(name="Educational Attainment",
                     values = c("Less Than HS Diploma"="deepskyblue",
                                "HS Diploma" = "firebrick1",
                                "Some College / Associate's Degree"="mediumpurple",
                                "Bachelor's Degree and Higher"="springgreen4"))+
  ggtitle("Unemployment Rate by Educational Attainment") +
  xlab("Time") +
  ylab("Unemployment Rate") +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent) +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5), legend.position="bottom")+
  labs(color='Class',fill='Class')
```