# Plot a line graph with different collors for each client in R

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2

I have a data frame that stores a client on each line, and in each column I have a model, like this:

```
Client   Model_1      Model_2      Model_3    Model_4      Model_5
    1       10.34        0.22        0.62        0.47         1.96
    2        0.97        0.60        0.04        0.78         0.19
    3        2.01        0.15        0.27        0.49         0.00
    4        0.57        0.94        0.11        0.66         0.00
    5        0.68        0.65        0.26        0.41         0.50
    6        0.55        3.59        0.06        0.01         5.50
    7       10.68        1.08        0.07        0.16         0.20
```

I need to plot a line graph where each client is a line, and the x-axis is the model (just the name)

I've searched some examples with ggplot2 but only using columns as the lines, I couldn't do it the way I want, so I'm here, thanks.

Comment: This might be helpful: [Plotting two variables as lines using ggplot2 on the same graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3777174/plotting-two-variables-as-lines-using-ggplot2-on-the-same-graph). You need to reshape your data from wide to long format as described in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3777592/8583393

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this. The key with `ggplot2` is reshaping to long as **@markus** cited in his comment:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)
#Code
df %>% pivot_longer(-Client) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=name,y=value,color=factor(Client),group=factor(Client)))+
  geom_line()+
  xlab('Client')+
  theme_bw()+
  labs(color='Client')
```

Output:

[image]

Some data used:

```
#Data
df <- structure(list(Client = 1:7, Model_1 = c(10.34, 0.97, 2.01, 0.57, 
0.68, 0.55, 10.68), Model_2 = c(0.22, 0.6, 0.15, 0.94, 0.65, 
3.59, 1.08), Model_3 = c(0.62, 0.04, 0.27, 0.11, 0.26, 0.06, 
0.07), Model_4 = c(0.47, 0.78, 0.49, 0.66, 0.41, 0.01, 0.16), 
    Model_5 = c(1.96, 0.19, 0, 0, 0.5, 5.5, 0.2)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))
```

Comment: this worked, but in my problem i have 30 clients, so the plot got really messy, do you know any way of making it prettier?

Comment: @ArturBraga Do you mean the legend? In that case you will get a messy legend, or what do you refer by messy?

Comment: I meant the lines... but i guess that there is no way of 30 lines in a plot don't get messy

Comment: anyway, thank you :)

Comment: The other think you could do is splitting the customers in two groups and use facet_wrap()

Answer (score 1):

We can use `matplot` from `base R` (No use of packages)

```
matplot(`colnames<-`(t(df1[-1]), df1$Client), type = 'l', ylab = 'value')

legend("top", colnames(df1[-1]),col=df1$Client,cex=0.8,fill=df1$Client)
```

-output
[image]

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Client = 1:7, Model_1 = c(10.34, 0.97, 2.01, 0.57, 
0.68, 0.55, 10.68), Model_2 = c(0.22, 0.6, 0.15, 0.94, 0.65, 
3.59, 1.08), Model_3 = c(0.62, 0.04, 0.27, 0.11, 0.26, 0.06, 
0.07), Model_4 = c(0.47, 0.78, 0.49, 0.66, 0.41, 0.01, 0.16), 
    Model_5 = c(1.96, 0.19, 0, 0, 0.5, 5.5, 0.2)), class = "data.frame",
    row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))
```

Comment: sorry i wrote the question wrong, but i edited it

Comment: and i really wanted to use ggplot2 to get some prettier plots, it's for a presentation, but thanks